# align vs equation

Tags: equations, amsmath

I always use `align` in my documents, and avoid `equation`. Is there anything wrong with that? My reasoning behind this: align > equation, so why not use it?

Comment: Related [Why should I ever use equation when I can always use align?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/49574/49576#comment187794_49576)

Answer (score 74):

While not exactly a bad idea in principle, unfortunately it *is* a bad idea in practise because `align` doesn't have the same feature as `equation` whereby less vertical space is added if a small equation is displayed after a paragraph that ended early on the line. For example, consider

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
hello
\[
a+b=c
\]

hello
\begin{align}
a+b&=c
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

You should easily be able to see the extra space after the second ‘hello’.

[image]

Comment: What are you supposed to do though if you need to use an `align` environment (i.e., if typeseting an `equation` environment with an `aligned` inside is not sufficient)?

Comment: If you need to use `align` then you just use `align` :) Just be aware of the difference, that's all.

Comment: I've tried this code with the `[fleqn]` option and `\setlength{\mathindent}{0pt}` and they look exactly the same.

Comment: Another point is: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/102174/36389

Answer (score 49):

`equation` "squeezes" the math (i.e. uses less white space between symbols) in order to avoid badboxes but `align` does not.

```
\documentclass[11pt,draft]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
 Using ``equation'':
 \begin{equation*}
  1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9+10
  = 11+12+13+14+15+16+17+18+19+20+21
 \end{equation*}

 Using ``align'':
 \begin{align*}
  1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9+10
  = 11+12+13+14+15+16+17+18+19+20+21\\
 \end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I guess what you're showing is that an `align[*]` environment, if used mindlessly (or recklessly...), more easily produces seriously overfull lines of math than does an `equation[*]` environment. Of course, one rather good reason for using an `align` environment to begin with is to have a method for avoiding the creation such overfull lines.

Comment: @Mico Exactly!...which is why I was so surprised when I noticed this behavior in one of my papers. I used to be like the OP and thought `align` > `equation` used thus used `align` everywhere. The only argument I had seen to use `equation` is because you want the syntax reflect this. However, I often have multi-lined equation that need alignment and even tend to edit equation so the that the need for alignment comes and goes. I found it an annoying waste of time to change the syntax between `align` and `equation`.

Comment: Eventually are stated using `equation` for one liners just because my coauthors did. Only in the last week have I realized that there is a visible difference between these two environments (primarily this answer of mine and Will's answer about differing vertical white space before the display math).

Answer (score 25):

Will all due respect to Will Robertson, actually I think that it is a bad idea in principle, because they mean different things and markup (be it *TeX, HTML,...) should be logical as much as possible.

If you are typesetting an equation, then use `equation` and if you desire alignment you can use `aligned` blocks inside the equation.

You can decide easily whether you are typesetting an equation or not, by thinking how to want to reference it.  If you only want one equation number to be displayed and see yourself suppressing by hand any additional equation numbers, (say by using `\notag`) then you are typesetting an equation and your markup should reflect that.

Comment: I see what you mean about markup being logical and do agree with you in principle, but I think in this case the typesetting of the output is far more important than whether or not we can consider a single equation to be aligned with itself (and therefore 'logical' within an `align` environment).  The difference in behaviour outlined by Will seems to me to provide a much better answer as to the actual difference between the two environments and where you could possibly run into trouble by choosing one over the other.

Comment: I interpret "not exactly a bad idea" as a polite way of saying not really a good idea.

Answer (score 17):

`align` is unable to replicate the label behavior of `equation + split`, which is to have a single vertically centered label.  One can suppress labels for specific lines of `align` using either `\nonumber` or `\notag`, but all unaltered lines get their own label.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
 Using ``equation'':
 \begin{equation}
  \begin{split}
   a+b
   &= c\\
   &= c\\
   &= c\\
   &= c
  \end{split}
 \end{equation}

 Using ``align'':
 \begin{align}
  a+b
  &= c\\
  &= c \notag\\
  &= c \nonumber\\
  &= c
 \end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image]

(Answer inspired by [this source](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/49574/why-should-i-ever-use-equation-when-i-can-always-use-align/49576#49576).)

Comment: It's [possible to use `split` inside `align` too](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/3767/15665). (Also, interestingly, somehow the `split`s will try to align properly to the `&` anchors outside of them, according to one of the answers on that page.)

Comment: What about 'align + aligned'?

Comment: The `aligned` environment can be used within `align` to obtain the same behavior.

Comment: You can use use `aligned`, `alignedat` (or `split` (\*)) inside `equation` or `align` (or even `alignedat` (\*)). If in you get an error in the combination marked by star, look [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/3769/302342) for how `split` tries to align its `&` with the outer environment.  In most cases I use `aligned` inside `equation`.

Answer (score 11):

if you are using both `amsmath` and `amsthm`, you end a proof with a one-line equation, and want to move the qed box up onto the line with the equation, `align` will happily overprint the box onto the end of the math.  `equation` behaves.  so does `\[ ... \]`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\begin{document}
\begin{proof}
one-line display with \verb+align*+
\begin{align*}
 a + b = c \qedhere
\end{align*}
\end{proof}
\begin{proof}
one-line display with \verb+equation*+
\begin{equation*}
 a + b = c \qedhere
\end{equation*}
\end{proof}
\begin{proof}
one-line display with \verb+\[+ \dots\verb+\]+
\[
 a + b = c \qedhere
\]
\end{proof}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Edit:**
This should have been stated in the original formulation of the
answer, but was overlooked.

The real problem with this use of `align` is that `align` expects and *requires* an odd number of `&`s to work properly.

Briefly, the purpose of `align` is to set adjacent equations so that a specified point in each (marked by `&`) is positioned in the same horizontal location in all lines of a multi-line display.  Since more than one component equation may appear on each line, these components are in turn separated by `&`, hence the requirement for an odd number of them.  Furthermore, `align` should not be used for single-line displays; that's what `equation` (or `\[ ... \]` for the unnumbered variety) is for.  See the `amsmath` user guide for details (`texdoc amsldoc`).

Comment: This seems like a bug in the `amsthm` package?

Comment: @rubenvb looks more like user error to me:-)

Comment: @rubenvb `\qedhere` should be on the right hand side of the alignment, after `&`

Comment: @rubenvb I confirm: `\qedhere` in `align`, `flalign` or `alignat` requires at least one `&`.

Comment: @rubenvb -- but using an environment designed for a multi-line display for a one-line display is still bad practice.

Comment: @barbarabeeton one could also argue that designing an environment that can only handle multiline input is bad implementation. But I get your point and this discussion is becoming philosophical quite quickly :).

Comment: A colleague tells me that equation is deprecated. He is in favor of align. Is this true?

Comment: `equation` is absolutely *not* deprecated.  I have no idea where your colleague got *that* idea.  Instead, `align` is deprecated *for one-line displays* (or at least seriously discouraged).  Use of `align` for one-liners is one of the most serious user errors that I know; having been one of the group involved in the design of the original math package, I assure you that `equation` is intentionally designed to handle single-line displays as well as *any* conceptually "unitary" displayed structure that has a single equation number.  Read the `amsmath` documentation (`texdoc amsldoc`).

Comment: Thanks very much for this! I myself prefer equation and would have been very sad to see it go.

Comment: @user3236841 your colleague is thinking of `equalign`