# Which command should I use for displayed equations?

Tags: math-mode, equations, amsmath

A number of related questions have already been asked about this issue:

- [align vs equation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/321/align-vs-equation)
- [which is preferable to](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/503/why-is-preferable-to)
- [what to do with this hyperref note on amsmath](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/975/what-to-do-with-this-hyperref-note-on-amsmath)
- and even [eqnarray vs align](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/196/eqnarray-vs-align)

But I'm still confused by the conflicting suggestions that have been given so far. So I'm trying again.

**Which should be the preferred command to produce a displayed equation in my LaTeX documents?**

So far the suggestions indicate that one should use `\[ ... \]`, maybe `\begin{equation*} ... \end{equation*}`, or maybe even the `gather*` or `align*` environments from `amsmath`.

And one should definitely **avoid** using either `$$...$$` or the `eqnarray` environment.

Now I have to say that, from a language perspective, I have a *strong* preference for the `equation*` environment because it is less cryptic than the `\[ ... \]` notation and it is [semantically](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/605/what-is-the-deal-about-these-semantic-vs-syntactic-commands) the most accurate.

So, is it fine to use `equation*`? Maybe only after loading `amsmath`? Or should the `equation`/`equation*` environment be redefined to something else so that spacing, package support, or whatever is improved?

Comment: This is wishful thinking, but I would so very much like the different displayed equation environments to all be the *same* environment with different arguments.  So, \begin{equation}{centered}...\end{equation}, \begin{equation*}{aligned}...\end{equation*}, etc.  Then if I want alignment I have only to change one word.

Comment: @ryan: It's not exactly what you're asking for, but I think you would like the breqn package.

Comment: `amsmath.sty` contains these lines: `\DeclareRobustCommand{\[}{\begin{equation*}} \DeclareRobustCommand{\]}{\end{equation*}}`. So `\[…\]` is exactly identical to the `equation*` environment when the `amsmath` package is loaded.

Comment: @Jaun: Can you elaborate why one should not use $$...$$ or eqnarray in specifics. What are the pros...cons. Thanks

Comment: @night: as far as I know, they tend to have problems with spacing. You can find more info about this on the answers bellow, or the links on my question.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You should use the environments from amsmath. In practice, `equation` and `align` are all you usually need.

- If you have a single equation, use `equation`. (Or `equation*` if you don't want it numbered. Most of the other environments below also have similar * variants.)
- If you have a single equation spanning multiple lines, you can either use `multline`, or use `split` (inside `equation`) to have the parts aligned.
- If you have multiple equations and you want them to be aligned, use `align` (or `align*`).
- If you simply want to typeset multiple equations independently (with no alignment), use `gather`.

There are also `flalign` and `alignat`, for some special cases. See the [Short Math Guide for LaTeX](ftp://ftp.ams.org/pub/tex/doc/amsmath/short-math-guide.pdf) or `texdoc amsldoc` ([PDF](ftp://ftp.ams.org/pub/tex/doc/amsmath/amsldoc.pdf)) for more documentation on these environments.

`\[` simply says "set the following in a math display", like plain TeX 's `$$` (which you should not use), and is equivalent to `displaymath`. You can use it if you want an unnumbered equation and are too lazy to type (not good practice, semantically speaking), or, I guess, when you're simply "displaying" some long bit of mathematics that isn't an actual equation. And [never use](http://www.tug.org/pracjourn/2006-4/madsen/) [eqnarray](http://texblog.net/latex-archive/maths/eqnarray-align-environment/).

Comment: Sounds good! This is pretty much what I already do. So is there any reason one should want to use `\[` instead of `equation*`? Or is it better just to forget about `\[` altogether?

Comment: When you're too lazy to type `equation*`, I guess. :-) Or when something you want "displayed" isn't an actual equation. I added this to the answer, but it's probably fine in practice to simply forget about `\[` altogether.

Comment: Emacsen (with AUCTeX) autocomplete many environments, so you can be lazy and still use `equation*` :)

Comment: Don't forget about the -ed versions of the environments. The `aligned` environment, in particular is extremely useful for numbering a group of equations with a single alignment with a single number.

Comment: Is there any reason to use `equation`? Why not use `align` all the time? When my equation has a single line, will the `align` environment format it differently from an `equation` environment?

Comment: @Bruce Connor: Yes, there is good reason to use `equation` when there's a single equation. See the question [align vs equation](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/321/align-vs-equation) (already the first link in the question, actually).

Comment: `\[ \]` is just the same as `equation*` environment with `amsmath`, or `displaymath` without `amsmath`. It's safe and convenience to use them. With proper code formatting, `\[ \]` is also quite readable. On the other hand, `$$` should be forgot.

Answer (score 12):

The `equation` environment cannot be compared to `\[...\]` because it's *numbered*. The equivalent to `\[...\]` is the `displaymath` environment. So you may use that for unnumbered equations.

Though amsmath redefines equation to allow a starred version.

As using amsmath is always recommended, using `equation` and `equation*` might be more consistent.

`$$` and `eqnarray` are out of question, whereas `gather`, `align` and the like are designed for multi-line formulas, I wouldn't misuse them for single-line equations.

Comment: I was trying to save on `*`'s on the question, and that's why I added a note, but yes I mean `equation*`. In any case, what about the issues raised [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/975/what-to-do-with-this-hyperref-note-on-amsmath)?

Comment: If `gather` or `align` could replace `equation` completely, why doesn't amsmath replace `equation`... On the other hand, amsmath introduces a different spacing for multi-line equations, not for single-line equations. There might be a reason. If a multi-line equation like `gather`/`align` is opened, amsmath adds slightly more space expecting more lines. Writing just a single line denies that expectation.

Comment: So the answer to *that* question is that one *should* use `equation` and not any replacement? (none of the answers to that question have been up-voted yet)

Answer (score 12):

full disclosure: i have a built-in bias towards amsmath.

although in most cases, `\[`...`\]` is comparable to the equation* environment, there's one place where it isn't.  if you are using an ams document class, a qed marker is automatically placed by the `\end{proof}`.  if the proof ends with some other environment -- a display or list -- the qed marker is placed all by itself on the line below.

if your proof ends with an unnumbered display, you probably want the qed marker to be placed on the same line as the display.  `\qedhere`, placed just before the `\end{...}` environment for the display will move the qed marker up into the scope of the display.  but it won't work for `\[...\]`, and it won't work for `\begin{eqnarray}...\end{eqnarray}`.  (it will also work for `\end{enumerate}` and `\end{itemize}`, but that wasn't the question here.)

Comment: `\qedhere` *seems* to work with `proof` + `\[...\]`. Could you perhaps give an example that shows how it fails?

Comment: @Jukka: If you use amsmath then it _has_ to work; see Philipp's comment to the question.

Comment: i was wrong about \qedhere not working with \\[...\\] -- sometimes the brain just takes a vacation.  apologies for the confusion.