# About big parenthesis larger than Bigg

Tags: amsmath, scaling, delimiters, multline

Do any one know how to type a very big parenthesis in LaTeX. Since the formula is very big, I used `multline` environment, in one line, there are many pair of parenthesis by using `\left` and `\right` which make them already very big. Between lines, I need some parenthesis bigger than the one given by `\Bigg`. My intention is to show the following big formula in `multline` environment:

```
$$
\frac{
      e^{-\frac{t \lambda +4}{4 \lambda \nu }}
      \left(
            e^{\frac{t}{4 \nu }}
            \left(
                  4 \sqrt{\pi } \sqrt{\nu }+1
            \right)
            \nu \Phi
            \left(
                  \frac{t-\frac{2}{\lambda }}{\sqrt{2} \sqrt{t \nu }}
            \right)
            \lambda^3
            -e^{\frac{t \lambda +8}{4 \lambda \nu }}
            \left(
                  4 \sqrt{\pi } \sqrt{\nu }-1
            \right)
            \nu
            \left(
                  \Phi
                  \left(
                        \frac{t+\frac{2}{\lambda }}{\sqrt{2} \sqrt{t \nu }}
                  \right)
                  -1
            \right)
            \lambda^3
            +e^{\frac{1}{\lambda \nu }}
            \left(
                  4 \sqrt{\pi } \lambda^3 \nu^{3/2}
                  \left(
                        2 \Phi
                        \left(
                              \frac{1}{\sqrt{2} \lambda \sqrt{t \nu }}
                        \right)
                        -1
                  \right)
                  -e^{\frac{t}{4 \nu }}
                  \left(
                        \left(
                              \lambda
                              \left(
                                    4 \sqrt{\pi } \sqrt{\nu }-1
                              \right)
                              \nu +2
                        \right)
                        \lambda^2+2
                        (\lambda \nu -2)
                        \Phi
                        \left(
                              \frac{\sqrt{\frac{t}{\nu }}}{\sqrt{2}}
                        \right)
                        \lambda^2-2
                   \right)
             \right)
       \right)
     }{4 \lambda }
$$
```

Comment: (tried to clean up the code a little for you)

Comment: Note that `$$ ... $$` should not be used for displayed math, cf. l2tabu: https://ctan.org/pkg/l2tabu

Comment: @Torbjorn, shall we use "\\[   \\]" instead? Thanks. :-)

Comment: @anand: Yes, that or the `equation*` environment. Sorry, should have mentioned this in my previous comment. See also [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/503/why-is-preferable-to) and [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1166/which-command-should-i-use-for-displayed-equations-really).

Comment: Related Question:[Big Parenthesis in an Equation](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/38868/big-parenthesis-in-an-equation).

Answer (score 53, accepted):

The ams parenthesis of specific size are typeset by using `\left` and `\right` and putting in an invisible "thing" of a certain height to ensure that they are big enough.  Mimicking that, you could do: `\left(\rule{0cm}{2cm}\right.` to get a left parenthesis of 2cm height.  Note that the AMS command also adds a little horizontal space which you might need to put in as well.  If you do this often, you could easily define new sizes:

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\vast}{\bBigg@{4}}
\newcommand{\Vast}{\bBigg@{5}}
\makeatother
```

Then in your document:

```
\[
\Vast( \frac{\prod_0^\infty k}{\sum_0^\infty n} \Vast)
\]
```

produces:

[image: big parentheses]

I recommend also taking a look at [Vertically asymmetric size variation for parentheses](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1023/86) about vertically centring parentheses.

(**Note** I've assumed that you're using `amsmath` since you tag it with `amsmath` and the commands `\big` and so forth are ones that `amsmath` produces.  If you're using a different package to get these commands, then this solution won't work.)

Comment: Thank you Andrew. It is very useful. It solves my problem. :-)

Comment: very useful
thanks a lot
you are an angel !!

Comment: Great, but your code should also define `\vastl`, `\vastm`, and `\vastr` commands that work along the lines of `\bigl`, `\bigm`, and `\bigr`, right? Also `\Vastl`, `\Vastm`, and `\Vastr`?

Comment: \left(\rule{0cm}{2cm}\right. Worked for me!  IN my case I used the curly bracket instead of the parenthesis.  I even taylored the hight parameter, by trial and error, of the \rule to size the bracket just right.  In my case I used em instead of cm so that it SHOULD self re-size if the font is ever changed. vis. 
\left.\rule{0em}{2.5em}\right\}

Answer (score 3):

I had the same requirement as Anand and came across this page. The solution recommended by Loop Space works flawlessly. However, when the equations are already too complex, typing `\left(\rule{0cm}{2cm}\right.` inside the math environment adds to the clutter. Therefore, I declared the following commands in my preamble and call them with the required height where it is necessary.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[cmex10]{amsmath}

\newcommand{\prb}[1]{\mathop{\mathrm{Pr}}\nolimits \left\{ {#1} \right\} }

\newcommand{\cstpl}[1]{\left(\rule{0 cm}{#1}\right.}
\newcommand{\cstpr}[1]{\left.\rule{0 cm}{#1}\right)}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
& Q = \cstpl{0.8cm} \prb{\frac{A^2_i}{B+C^3_i} \ge D } - \\
& \prb{\frac{E^2_j}{F^2_k+G} \ge H } \frac{ L }{ M } \cstpr{0.8cm}.
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! The `cmex10` option to `amsmath` is for compatibility with very old TeX distributions and should not be used with newer (later than 1998 or so) ones.