# Big Parenthesis in an Equation

Tags: math-mode, delimiters

I have an equation contained inside `\[...\]`, which automatically makes a `\sum` with sub- and superscripts turn big--so that the summation sign looks awkward inside parenthesis.  Any idea how to make the parenthesis completely enclose the whole summation?

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
We have:
\[ \sum_{i=1}^n i = (\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} i) + n =
\frac{(n-1)(n)}{2} + n = \frac{n(n+1)}{2} \]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Use \left( for the opening bracket and \right) for the closing one. These will automatically adjust their height to fit the contents.

Comment: Related Question: [About big parenthesis larger than Bigg](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6794/about-big-parenthesis-larger-than-bigg).

Answer (score 385, accepted):

The usual thing to do is replace `(` with `\left(` and `)` with `\right)`, which automatically expand to fit the material between them. Note that every `\left...` requires a `\right...` (but the type of bracket may be different, i.e. `\left(...\right]` also works).

I would typeset your equation as

```
\begin{equation*}
\sum_{i=1}^n i = \left(\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} i\right) + n =
\frac{(n-1)(n)}{2} + n = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}
\end{equation*}
```

[image]

For manual control of sizes (most of the time you *won't* need these)

```
( \big( \Big( \bigg( \Bigg(
```

produce

[image]

Comment: Thanks!  But when I try `\left( \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} i \right) + n`, the big parenthesis around the sum look very awkward--tall with little curvature.  Is this a problem with the way I'm coding it, or might it just be the font (I'm using the Arev font via `\usepackage{fouriernc}`)?

Comment: Also, why use `\begin{equation*}...\end{equation*}` instead of just `\[...\]`?

Comment: The environment I use is from the amsmath package, so yours is actually more general. I just find \[...\] to look messy. Alternatively there is the displaymath environment.

Comment: @jamaicanworm: [`amsmath`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath) defines `\[...\]` to be *exactly* the same as `\begin{equation*}...\end{equation*}`. See, literally, the last couple of lines of [`amsmath.sty`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/required/amslatex/math/amsmath.sty).

Comment: And by "type of bracket" you also mean that they can be "inverted", like: `\left]...\right(`.

Comment: @jamaicanworm The shape of the brackets is down to the font I'm afraid. If you don't like the larger curved brackets, try the square ones `\left[...\right]`. These often look better for larger equations. Another thing to take into account is that you're enclosing something relatively thin in those brackets. I suspect it will only look more natural when there's more between them (try putting the `n` to the left of the sum and loosing the brackets altogether).

Comment: I would be a bit careful using `\left/right` around sums etc. because they often become too large. I tend to recommend users to: Scale the fences (parenteses and such) such that it is clear to the read what they fence in, but not to such an extend that the fences dominate the expression.

Comment: Out of topic comment: You might have already  known [it](http://tug.org/tug2013/).

Comment: @Karl'sstudents Known what?

Comment: TUG 2013 conference in Tokyo, click the hyperlink in the "it" above.

Comment: @MarkS.Everitt I disagree with this comment of yours "most of the times you won't need these" about the `\big...` family of commands. In fact, I personally believe that most of the times one shouldn't use the `\left...\right` construct; the family of `\big...` commands produces much better spacing (both vertically and horizontally) in most situations; besides you don't need to match them across lines in a display.

Comment: You're right. I should have written a comment here. I apologize for that. After some minutes, I will delete this comment and the one in egreg's answer.

Comment: I've found that second guessing LaTeX is usually the wrong thing to do. In any case I myself only need to manually size a bracket now and then, so the comment is consistent with my experience.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work if you use  the equation in a `multline` environment.

Comment: @qubyte BRILLIANT. THANKS SO MUCH.  [+1]

Comment: can `\left(` discard `underbrace` text?

Answer (score 61):

Automatically sized parentheses are obtained with `\left` and `\right`, as any LaTeX guide or manual tells.

However, automatic sizing is not good in every case; one of these cases is precisely that of summations with limits above and below: compare the results of

```
\[
\left( \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} i \right)\biggl(\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} i\biggr)
\]
```

[image]

(the font is that obtained with `\usepackage{fouriernc}`). In general the second way is to be preferred.

Comment: Do you have a reference explaining why the size is bad on the left sum?

Comment: @VincentGuillemot The TeXbook, for instance.

Comment: OK, thks. Let me rephrase my comment: the argument "it's prettier" (used in the TeXBook) leaves me a little bit disappointed. Isn't there a more substantial reason hidden behind this aspiration to prettyness?

Comment: I find the former to be prettier.

Comment: Prettier or not, sometimes some publications simply require the right style and then this answer comes so handy! However with today's MikTex I am getting `File `fouriernc.sty' not found.` and it looks like just including the package is not enough. This file has to beinstalled manually.

Answer (score 42):

One way is using `\left` and `\right`, followed by the parenthesis you want to use. These are mostly `()` `[]` `{}` `\langle\rangle` and `|`. You can also use a `.` to have no parenthesis displayed, e.g. when you want an opening, but no closing one.

```
\left( \frac12 \right)
\quad
\left\langle \frac23 \right.
\quad
\left\{ \frac34 \right]
```

creates

[image]

If you want to control the size manually, use (in ascending order) \big, \Big, \bigg, \Bigg.

```
( \frac12 \big)
\quad
\Bigg\langle \frac23 \big]
\quad
\Big\{ \frac34 \Bigg.
```

results in

[image]

Comment: One should use `\bigl` in front of the left delimiter and `\bigr` in front of the right delimiter (similarly for `\Bigl`-`\Bigr` and the others). This is important for spacing.

Comment: @egreg: When should one use just plain `\big` and friends? i.e., without the `l`|`r` suffix?

Comment: `\big` and friends can go in front of ordinaries: `\big/` or `\big|`.

Comment: @egreg at least as long as `\big|` is not a part of a pair: `\big|-x\big|\neq \bigl|-x\bigr|`

Comment: I was just looking for a way to adjust `{` size by the formula inclosed in it. I used `\left{`. your answer was great. it learned me to use `\left\{` instead