# Breaking a long math expression

Tags: math-mode, line-breaking, amsmath

I am trying to type long expression by using parenthesis inserting some sentences, as an example I have a expression like product of

```
\documentclass{12 pt}{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{multline}
(product of (A\times_{c} B) by C)\times_{c} D) by E.
\end{multline}
\end{document}
```

I am using `multline` environment but I have problem with breaking into different lines. Is there any easy way to break the lines?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Without knowing anything about what you're doing, I predict that the problem is that your parentheses are paired using `\left(` and `\right)`.  These cannot be broken across lines; if you need both large parentheses and line breaks, you will need to select their sizes manually.  See [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/38870/575), for example, for a list of sizes.

Comment: Thank you – Torbjørn T. I have a expression like product of (product of (A\times_{c} B) by C)\times_{c} D) by E.

Comment: Does that answer your question?  I can make it an answer instead of a comment.  But, please, edit your question with a minimal example showing what you intend.

Comment: @ Ryan, I will edit the question now. Still, i am not getting the exact answer but I was looking exactly what you are writing in your comment.

Comment: TeX code would be preferable.  Read the link that @TorbjørnT provided.

Comment: @RyanReich You wrote "you will need to select their sizes manually". What if the OP used `\left(...\right. \\ \left. ... \right)`? That would work, wouldn't it?

Comment: Do your formulae really span that much vertical space? Because for the MWE you provided, i would (especially together with the sentence) rather use inline math, i.e. `\bigl(product of (A\times_{c} B) by C\bigr)\times_{c} D by E.` (where i deleted your unbalanced paranthesis after `D`) and used the slightly bigger braces from `amsmath` which still fit into one line.

Comment: @Jubobs That works but only gives brackets of matching sizes if each `...` expression has the same height/depth.

Comment: @AndrewSwann I would personally favour using brackets of matching size anyway; I think it allows readers to identify pairs of opening/closing brackets more easily.

Comment: @Jubobs So would I - I was just commenting on your "That would work"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [mathmode](http://www.tex.ac.uk/ctan/info/math/voss/mathmode/Mathmode.pdf) document by Herbert Voß provides an example how to use the multiline environment on page 51. The easy way to break lines is adding \\ at the position where you want the line break to occur.

Answer (score 3):

It is quite hard to answer your question as the example code supplied doesn't give many clues.
However `[12pt]` needs to be in square brackets, and you need to mark up text in math specially (I'm using `\text` from the `amsmath` package). Then line breaks can be marked with `\\`

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{multline}
(\text{product of} \\
  (A\times_{c} B) \text{ by } C \\
  )\times_{c} D)\text{ by } E \text{.}.
\end{multline}
\end{document}
```