# What is the process of installing the packages required to use the fouriernc?

Tags: miktex, fourier

Using this answer to typeset the tall brackets [Big Parenthesis in an Equation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/38868/big-parenthesis-in-an-equation) I included the `fouriernc` package but could not compile due to the following error in /AppData/Local/MiKTeX/2.9/miktex/log/miktex-makepk.log (after having to manually add the package as MikTex manager failed to install it for some reason):

[image]

```
2017-02-05 12:56:01,976-0500 INFO  makex - Trying to make PK font fourier-mex at 604 DPI...
2017-02-05 12:56:01,992-0500 INFO  makex - Running miktex-makemf.exe...
2017-02-05 12:56:02,123-0500 INFO  makex - Running ttf2pk.exe...
2017-02-05 12:56:02,311-0500 FATAL miktex-makepk - PK font fourier-mex could not be created.
```

What is the process to get this font?

Comment: You *should* install it with MiKTeX Package Manager (preferably as Admin).

Comment: I have, like I said.

Comment: You said you installed it manually?

Comment: I thought I had said that. Like, MikTex manager failed to install it... Had to add it manually...

Comment: Retry, and check first no other MiKTeX executable is not working (such as the compiler waiting for an answer). Once it is installed, run from the command line (as admin) `updmap.exe ---verbose` (the switch is to display what's happening). This will refresh the type 1 fonts databases.

Comment: Did you mean to try compilation or to try installing the package again?

Comment: Install it again. Then run the updmap thing.

Comment: This worked once I removed an extra dash from the suggested command above.

Comment: Sorry for mistyping!