# Writing an equation without italic font - chemistry packages

Tags: fonts, packages, chemistry, chemformula

I am dealing with two issues:

- First i need to write chemistry expressions like the one shown below
  not with italic but with upright font.
- Second i want to know if there is any useful chemistry package for
  those kind of formulaes. And if it is, can you use it with the formulaes in the image?It will be helpful.

The **MWE** of what is shown below is the next:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{nccmath}

\begin{document}

Los equilibrios paralelos del $ATP$, $ADP$ y $P_i$ a un pH cercano a 7 permiten reescribir $K_1$ del siguiente modo:
\begin{align*}
    K_1&=\frac{[ADP][P_i]}{[ADP]} \\[1em]
    K_1&=\frac{\big([ADP^{3-}]+[HADP^{2-}]+[MgADP^-]\big)\times\big([HPO_4^{2-}]+[H_2PO_4^-]+[MgHPO_4]\big)}{[ATP]^{4-}+[HATP]^{3-}+
[MgATP^{2-}]} \\[1em]
    K_1&=K\times\left\lgroup\frac{\left(1+\mfrac{10^{-pH}}{K_{HADP^{2-}}} + \mfrac{10^{-pMg}}{K_{MgADP^{-}}}\right)\times\left(1+\mfrac{10^{-pH}}{KH_2PO_4^{2-}}+\mfrac{10^{-pMg}}{K_{MgHPO_4}}\right)}{\left(1+\mfrac{10^{-pH}}{K_{ATP^{3-}}}+\mfrac{10^{-pMg}}{K_{MgATP^{-2}}}\right)\times10^{-pH}}\right\rgroup
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image: pdfimage generated with texmaker]

Thanks in advance..

Comment: For typesetting chemical formulae, you can use `mhchem` or `chemformula`.

Comment: As [suggested an hour ago](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/372861/how-to-control-large-fractions-and-multiple-spaces-between-paragraphs#comment922009_372861) `mhchem`  and `chemmacros`. A more complete list [can be found on mychemistry.eu](http://www.mychemistry.eu/known-packages/).

Comment: @Troy thanks. But i am not quite sure how to use it. That's one of the reasons for the post..

Comment: @santimirandarp For `mhchem`, use something like `\ce{ADP}`, for `chemformula`, use something like `\ch{ADP}`. Have you attempted to read the documentations of the above suggested packages?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's it for `chemformula`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{nccmath}
\usepackage{chemformula}

\begin{document}

Los equilibrios paralelos del \ch{ATP}, \ch{ADP} y \ch{P}$_{i}$ a un pH cercano 
a~$7$ permiten reescribir $K_1$ del siguiente modo:
\begin{align*}
K_1&=\frac{[\ch{ADP}][\ch{P}_{i}]}{[\ch{ADP}]} \\[1em]
K_1&=\frac{\bigl([\ch{ADP^3-}]+[\ch{HADP^2-}]+[\ch{MgADP^-}]\bigr)
           \times
           \bigl([\ch{HPO4^2-}]+[\ch{H2PO4^-}]+[\ch{MgHPO4}]\bigr)}
          {[\ch{ATP^4-}]+[\ch{HATP^3-}]+[\ch{MgATP^2-}]} \\[1em]
K_1&=K\times
  \left\lgroup
  \frac{\left(1+\mfrac{10^{-\ch{pH}}}{K_{\ch{HADP^2-}}}
        + \mfrac{10^{-\ch{pMg}}}{K_{\ch{MgADP^-}}}\right)
        \times
        \left(1+\mfrac{10^{-\ch{pH}}}{K_{\ch{H2PO4^2-}}}
        + \mfrac{10^{-\ch{pMg}}}{K_{\ch{MgHPO4}}}\right)}
       {\left(1+\mfrac{10^{-\ch{pH}}}{K_{\ch{ATP^3-}}}
        + \mfrac{10^{-\ch{pMg}}}{K_{\ch{MgATP^2-}}}\right)
        \times10^{-\ch{pH}}}
  \right\rgroup
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Great egreg, it was simple, i should have done it for myself, but was confused because there was not much information in the web about that package. It works, thanks.

Comment: @santimirandarp Don't search the web, get the package documentation. The documentation is just as free as the package and LaTeX, and it is installed (copied) to your computer while installing the package.

Comment: @santimirandarp you can find (almost) every LaTeX package on CTAN `http://www.ctan.org/pkg/<pkg>` and on your on computer using `texdoc <pkg>` on the command line. BTW: you might also want to take a look at the [`chemmacros`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/chemmacros) for stuff like `\pH`, …

Answer (score 1):

Ditto for all the other abbreviations.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{nccmath}
\newcommand{\ADP}{\mathrm{ADP}}

\begin{document}

Los equilibrios paralelos del $ATP$, $\ADP$ y $P_i$ a un pH cercano a 7 permiten reescribir $K_1$ del siguiente modo:
\begin{align*}
    K_1&=\frac{[\ADP][P_i]}{[\ADP]} \\[1em]
    K_1&=\frac{\big([\ADP^{3-}]+[HADP^{2-}]+[MgADP^-]\big)\times\big([HPO_4^{2-}]+[H_2PO_4^-]+[MgHPO_4]\big)}{[ATP]^{4-}+[HATP]^{3-}+
[MgATP^{2-}]} \\[1em]
    K_1&=K\times\left\lgroup\frac{\left(1+\mfrac{10^{-pH}}{K_{HADP^{2-}}} + \mfrac{10^{-pMg}}{K_{MgADP^{-}}}\right)\times\left(1+\mfrac{10^{-pH}}{KH_2PO_4^{2-}}+\mfrac{10^{-pMg}}{K_{MgHPO_4}}\right)}{\left(1+\mfrac{10^{-pH}}{K_{ATP^{3-}}}+\mfrac{10^{-pMg}}{K_{MgATP^{-2}}}\right)\times10^{-pH}}\right\rgroup
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This answer doesn't really include a chemistry related package, which the OP expicitely asked for.

Comment: True, which is why I upvoted the other answer.