# Using brackets for math

Tags: formatting, amsmath

The question is very simple:

Is there another type of bracket that can grow as the equation increases in size?

I wish it could look like this:

[image]

But unfortunately I only got this:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\int\int_D[\int_0^{16-x^2-y^2}(8+x+y)\,dz]\,dA
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/38868/big-parenthesis-in-an-equation

Comment: @samcarter the ghost of egreg will haunt you if you use `\bigg` rather than `\biggl...\biggr`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Oh no! I'm only about 6.5 hours away from him, with his motorcycle he could be here by witching hour!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I prefer this method using `\left[` and `\right]` which resizes for you:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\int\int_D\left[\int_0^{16-x^2-y^2}(8+x+y)\,dz\right]\,dA
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Which looks like this:
[image]

Or, taking Mico's good suggestion, you can write:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\iint_D\left[\int_0^{16-x^2-y^2}(8+x+y)\,dz\right]\,dA
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Which you can also see in some cases have a tendency to get overly large

Comment: @daleif Actually, the size matches the OP's desired picture quite well... And, I prefer the size myself.

Comment: For display math, Knuth strongly recommends (in the TeXbook) writing `\int\!\!\!\int` (three negative thinspaces). Since the `amsmath` package is loaded, one could also write `\iint`.

Comment: @Mico Thanks, I often forget I can do that.  Added it to my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Some suggestions:

- Use `\biggl[` and `\biggr]`, not `\left[` and `\right]`, to size the square brackets.
- Use `\iint` instead of `\int\int` for the pair of "outer" integral symbols.
- "Snug up" the integrand to the inner integral symbol by issuing the directive `\mkern-6mu` or, equivalently, the directive `\!\!` (two negative thinspaces). You may even try `\mkern-9mu` for a "really snug" look.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for "\iint" macro
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\iint_D\biggl[\int_0^{16-x^2-y^2}\mkern-6mu(8+x+y)\,dz\biggr]dA
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: would you mind to explain why you'd rather use `\biggl[` than `\left[`? I really appreciate the adaptability of the `left` kind of brackets. Is this not a notorious advantage?

Comment: @loved.by.Jesus - A hallmark of superior typography is *visual balance*. For the equation at hand, using `\left` and `\right` to auto-size the square brackets ends up producing brackets are needlessly big -- too big, in fact, thereby distracting from the material they enclose. At other times, `\left` and `\right` can produce delimiters that are not large enough. For a longer discussion see, e.g., [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/173771/5001) to the query [Is it ever bad to use \left and \right?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/173717/5001) [Shameless self-citation alert!]