# Cannot make bigger parentheses with \left \right

Tags: brackets

I try making my second pair of parenthesis bigger to match the picture using:

```
$$= p+(1-p)\left(1+ \mathbf E [X]\right)$$
```

[image: par]

Somehow, that doesn't work.  Can someone point out my error?

Comment: note you should not use `$$` in latex, there is no reason to enlarge the () here and latex does not by default but you could use `\bigl(1+...\bigr)` to force a larger size

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, I am using MathJax actually.

Comment: Amazing!  Your solution works!  Thanks.

Comment: even with mathjax `\[` rather than `$$` is the default

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Not really. For instance, in Math.SE one has to use `$$`. Or ``\\[`` and `\\]`

Comment: @egreg yes I know, but that's because they use a non-default configuration in the mathjax setup (to allow `$$`) and pass it through a markdown processor before mathjax sees it (which is why `\ ` needs to be doubled)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note you should not use `$$` in latex, there is no reason to enlarge the () here and latex does not by default but you could use

```
\bigl(1+...\bigr)
```

to force a larger size

Comment: Thank you!  I was copying from a note, and wish to match the original text as much as possible.

Answer (score 2):

A similar answer is in the following [link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/38868/big-parenthesis-in-an-equation). You can choose between the following options: **\bigl, \Bigl and \Biggl** . For example

```
\begin{equation}
    \Biggl( \Bigl( \bigl((a+b)^2\bigr)^2 \Bigr)^2 \Biggr)^2
\end{equation}
```

the output is:

[image: output example]

more Brackets and Parentheses in [link](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Brackets_and_Parentheses)
[image]

Comment: There's also `\vert` and `\Vert`, which end up being `|` and `||`, respectively.  The advantage of the former is that there's also `\lvert`, `\rvert`, `\lVert`, and `\rVert`, which end up being `|` and `||`, but having the appropriate interpretation of "left/right delimiter" which helps with the spacing.

Comment: Thank you for a barrage of an answer, gent!