# How to deal with underbrace inside parentheses?

Tags: equations, parenthesis

I have the following equation:

```
J_\pi(x_0)=\left(\underbrace{g_N(x_N)}_{\mathclap{\substack{\text{Terminal}
           \\\text{cost}}}}+\underbrace{\sum_{k=0}^{N-1}g_k(x_k,u_k,w_k)}_
           {\mathclap{\substack{\text{Accumulated}\\\text{cost}}}}\right)
```

Which outputs:

[image]

I want to get rid of the "extra height" on the parentheses (circled above in red) that's created due to the underbrace. How do I do this? Thank you!

**Solution**: I used `biggl` and `biggr` as per the suggestions, it works:

[image]

Thank you!

Comment: This is one of the typical situations where the automatic stretching of `\left` and `\right` overreacts. IMHO just set the delimiter size manually, like `\biggl(` and `\biggr)`.

Comment: Unrelated: the `\mathclap`s are superfluous here.

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/145865/underbrace-in-denominator-with-howto and http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/182749/underbrace-matrix-inside-brackets

Comment: Using the `\bigg` approach, if you want your underbraces to vertically align, try: `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,stackengine}
\begin{document}
\[
J_\pi(x_0)=\biggl(\underbrace{\addstackgap[10.6pt]{$g_N(x_N)$}}_{\mathclap{\substack{\text{Terminal}
           \\\text{cost}}}}+\underbrace{\sum_{k=0}^{N-1}g_k(x_k,u_k,w_k)}_
           {\mathclap{\substack{\text{Accumulated}\\\text{cost}}}}\biggr)
\]
\end{document}`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Even without underbraces you shouldn't use here `\left` ... `right`, as they give too high parentheses. There is family `\bigl`, `\Bigl`, `\biggl`, `\Biggl` and closing `\bigr` and so on. You can choose suitable height, using them, e.g.

```
\[
J_\pi(x_0)=\Biggl(\underbrace{g_N(x_N)}_{\mathclap{\substack{\text{Terminal}
           \\\text{cost}}}}+\underbrace{\sum_{k=0}^{N-1}g_k(x_k,u_k,w_k)}_
           {\mathclap{\substack{\text{Accumulated}\\\text{cost}}}}\Biggr)
\]
```