# How to add an underbrace to the part of the row vector?

Tags: math-mode, matrices, underbrace

My code is

```latex
    A = \left[\begin{matrix}
        1&\underbrace{\begin{matrix}
            1&\dotsb&1
        \end{matrix}}_N
    \end{matrix}\right]
```

and the outcome is
[image]

but I want the following outcome

[image]

How can I get this?

Comment: Welcome to the site.  Search is your friend.  Try "underbrace matrix" leads to answers like https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/182749/underbrace-matrix-inside-brackets.  There are many other possibilities, as well.

Answer (score 1):

Use `\smash` to hide the height of the `\underbrace` part. You can also drop the brackets, `\left[` and `\right]`, and use `bmatrix` or simply just `[ .. ]` around a `matrix`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[
A = \begin{bmatrix}
    1&\smash{\underbrace{\begin{matrix}
        1&\dotsb&1
    \end{matrix}}_N}
\end{bmatrix}
\]

\end{document}
```

> [image]

PS: The idea is the same as in the link provided by @StevenB.Segletes, I wrote the answer before searching ..