# Braces for cases in tabular environment

Tags: tables

I would like to create an aesthetic table with some cases within the table. I would like to denote the cases with braces from the left, as usual, like in the picture below (taken from http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Advanced_Mathematics):

[image: brace example]

My MWE is the following:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{lclr}
\toprule[1.5pt]
{ID} & {\#} & {Behaviour} & {Ave. peak} \\
\midrule
\multirow{4}{*}{\emph{dog} \Bigg\{ } & 1 & $1^{\mathrm{st}}$ torsion  & 12.3251 \\
 & 2 & $1^{\mathrm{st}}$ out-of-plane bending & 24.1345 \\
 & 3 & $1^{\mathrm{st}}$ in-plane bending & 54.1341 \\
 & 4 & $2^{\mathrm{nd}}$ torsion & 12.1234 \\[5pt]

\emph{kitten} & 1 & $1^{\mathrm{st}}$ torsion & 34.5431 \\

\bottomrule[1.5pt]
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Rendering as:

[image: rendered image]

The problem is only with the size of the brace, as it should be 4 row high in this case, 5 in other cases, etc. dynamically.

Thank you in advance,
Adam

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here are two ways you can do this:

1. **Large Brace**:

   You can specify a larger braces as per [About big parenthesis larger than Bigg](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6794/about-big-parenthesis-larger-than-bigg) to achieve:

   [image]

   This does however require manual intervention to select the size of the brace.
2. **\tikzmark**:

   Alternatively, you can use `tikzmark` to mark the important points of the brace and then use `tikz` to draw the brace. This is more flexible in that you don't need to tweak the code if you add/subtract rows plus provides a lot more flexibility in terms of how the brace is drawn:

   [image]

### Notes:

- In both solutions, I adjusted the inter column spacing. Remove this if it is not desired.
- The `\tikzmark` solution does require two runs. First one to determine the locations, and the second to do the drawing.
- The `\tikzmark` is from [Adding a large brace next to a body of text](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1559/adding-a-large-brace-next-to-a-body-of-text/1570#1570).

---

### Code `Bigger that \Big`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}

% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6794/about-big-parenthesis-larger-than-bigg
\makeatletter
    \newcommand{\vast}{\bBigg@{3}}
    \newcommand{\Vast}{\bBigg@{3.5}}
    \newcommand{\vastt}{\bBigg@{4}}
    \newcommand{\Vastt}{\bBigg@{4.5}}
    %%
    %% Size from smallest to largest:
    %%\[ ( \big( \Big( \bigg( \Bigg( \vast( \Vast( \vastt( \Vastt(\]
\makeatother


\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{l@{\hspace*{0.5em}}clr}% <-- @{} adjusted inter column space
\toprule[1.5pt]
{ID} & {\#} & {Behaviour} & {Ave. peak} \\
\midrule
\multirow{4}{*}{\emph{dog} \vastt\{ } & 1 & $1^{\mathrm{st}}$ torsion  & 12.3251 \\
 & 2 & $1^{\mathrm{st}}$ out-of-plane bending & 24.1345 \\
 & 3 & $1^{\mathrm{st}}$ in-plane bending & 54.1341 \\
 & 4 & $2^{\mathrm{nd}}$ torsion & 12.1234 \\[5pt]

\emph{kitten} & 1 & $1^{\mathrm{st}}$ torsion & 34.5431 \\

\bottomrule[1.5pt]
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

---

### Code: `\tikzmark`

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}

\newcommand{\tikzmark}[1]{\tikz[overlay,remember picture] \node (#1) {};}

\newcommand*{\BraceAmplitude}{0.4em}%
\newcommand*{\VerticalOffset}{0.5ex}%  
\newcommand*{\HorizontalOffset}{1.0em}% 
\NewDocumentCommand{\InsertLeftBrace}{%
    O{} % #1 = draw options
    O{\HorizontalOffset,\VerticalOffset} % #2 = optional brace shift options
    m   % #3 = top tikzmark
    m   % #4 = center tikzmark
    m   % #5 = bottom tikzmark
}{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
        \coordinate (Brace Top)    at ($(#4 |- #3.north) + (#2)$);
        \coordinate (Brace Bottom) at ($(#4 |- #5.south) + (#2)$);
    \draw [decoration={brace, amplitude=\BraceAmplitude}, decorate, thick, draw=blue, #1]
    (Brace Bottom) -- (Brace Top) ;
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}%


\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{l@{\hspace*{0.5em}}clr}% <-- @{} adjusted inter column space
\toprule[1.5pt]
{ID} & {\#} & {Behaviour} & {Ave. peak} \\
\midrule
\multirow{4}{*}{\emph{dog}\tikzmark{Center Mark}} & \tikzmark{Top Mark}1 & 
        $1^{\mathrm{st}}$ torsion  & 12.3251 \\
 & 2 & $1^{\mathrm{st}}$ out-of-plane bending & 24.1345 \\
 & 3 & $1^{\mathrm{st}}$ in-plane bending & 54.1341 \\
 & \tikzmark{Bottom Mark}4 & $2^{\mathrm{nd}}$ torsion & 12.1234 \\[5pt]

\emph{kitten} & 1 & $1^{\mathrm{st}}$ torsion & 34.5431 \\

\bottomrule[1.5pt]
\end{tabular}
\InsertLeftBrace[red, ultra thick]{Top Mark}{Center Mark}{Bottom Mark}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

With `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`and its built-in command `\SubMatrix`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{NiceTabular}{lclr}
    \toprule
    ID & \# & Behaviour & Ave. peak \\
    \midrule
    \Block{4-1}{\emph{dog}}
     & 1 & $1^{\mathrm{st}}$ torsion  & 12.3251 \\
     & 2 & $1^{\mathrm{st}}$ out-of-plane bending & 24.1345 \\
     & 3 & $1^{\mathrm{st}}$ in-plane bending & 54.1341 \\
     & 4 & $2^{\mathrm{nd}}$ torsion & 12.1234 \\[5pt]

    \emph{kitten} & 1 & $1^{\mathrm{st}}$ torsion & 34.5431 \\
    \bottomrule
\CodeAfter
    \SubMatrix{\{}{2-2}{5-2}{.}
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]