# Braces at the right of rows in a table

Tags: tables, bigdelim

I want to put a brace at the right of the rows in a table.

I use

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{multirow,bigdelim}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{cc}
\hline 
Sample values: each line contains one entire beat)\tabularnewline
\hline 
68.1 72.8 78.4 85.6 93.6 98.1 95.3 91.2 91.1 ... & \rdelim\{{3}{3mm}[variable length] \tabularnewline
74.4 79.2 85.6 92.8 100.8 108.8 115.2 121.6 ...\tabularnewline
73.6 77.6 84.0 91.2 100.0 108.8 117.6 124.8 ...\tabularnewline
\hline 
\end{tabular} 
\end{document}
```

which produces

[image]

How can I modify the code to inverse the direction of the brace, as the following screenshot shows?

[image]

I tried using `\rdelim` but it put the brace at the end:

[image]

Comment: Either you have just answered your question or I cannot see (important) difference betwen case 1 and 2.

Comment: @PrzemysławScherwentke Fixed!

Comment: So it is enough to change `\{` into `\}`.

Comment: @PrzemysławScherwentke Thanks, yes, I had misread the `\rdelim\{{3}` as `\rdelim\{3}`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Maybe just:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{multirow,bigdelim}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tabular}{cc}
    \hline
    Sample values: each line contains one entire beat)\tabularnewline
    \hline
    68.1 72.8 78.4 85.6 93.6 98.1 95.3 91.2 91.1 ... & \rdelim\}{3}{3mm}[variable length] \tabularnewline
    74.4 79.2 85.6 92.8 100.8 108.8 115.2 121.6 ...\tabularnewline
    73.6 77.6 84.0 91.2 100.0 108.8 117.6 124.8 ...\tabularnewline
    \hline
  \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image: flipped curly bracket]

## EDIT

You might also like to think about making the tabular slightly more elegant and legible:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{multirow,bigdelim,dcolumn,booktabs}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tabular}{*{9}{D{.}{.}{1}@{\hskip 7.5pt}}cc}
    \toprule
    \multicolumn{11}{c}{Sample values: each line contains one entire beat)}\tabularnewline
    \midrule
    68.1 &72.8 &78.4 &85.6 &93.6 &98.1 &95.3 &91.2 &91.1 &... & \rdelim\}{3}{17.5mm}[\parbox{12.5mm}{variable\\length}] \tabularnewline
    74.4 &79.2 &85.6 &92.8 &100.8 &108.8 &115.2 &121.6 &&...\tabularnewline
    73.6 &77.6 &84.0 &91.2 &100.0 &108.8 &117.6 &124.8 &&...\tabularnewline
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image: prettified?]

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt Since that seemed too easier I've added a slightly souped up version in an edit ;). (It is always easier to catch other people's typos because you don't know what they meant to write.)

Comment: It looks awesome, thanks a lot, I'll make sure I understand all the code to improve my future latex tables!

Answer (score 9):

You can also adapt the solution from [Braces for cases in tabular environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/206898/braces-for-cases-in-tabular-environment/) which allows you to mark the top and bottom using `\tikzmark` and then do the drawing afterwards:

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{multirow,bigdelim,dcolumn,booktabs}

\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}

\newcommand{\tikzmark}[1]{\tikz[overlay,remember picture] \node (#1) {};}

%% Adapted form https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/206898/braces-for-cases-in-tabular-environment/207704#207704
\newcommand*{\BraceAmplitude}{0.4em}%
\newcommand*{\VerticalOffset}{0.5ex}%  
\newcommand*{\HorizontalOffset}{0.0em}% 
\NewDocumentCommand{\InsertRightBrace}{%
    O{} % #1 = draw options
    O{\HorizontalOffset,\VerticalOffset} % #2 = optional brace shift options
    m   % #3 = top tikzmark
    m   % #4 = bottom tikzmark
    m   % #5 = node text
}{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
        \coordinate (Brace Top)    at ($(#3.north) + (#2)$);
        \coordinate (Brace Bottom) at ($(#4.south) + (#2)$);
    \draw [decoration={brace, amplitude=\BraceAmplitude}, decorate, thick, draw=blue, #1]
            (Brace Top) -- (Brace Bottom) 
            node [pos=0.5, anchor=west, align=left, text width=1.25cm, color=black, xshift=\BraceAmplitude] {#5};
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}%

\begin{document}
  \noindent
  \begin{tabular}{*{9}{D{.}{.}{1}@{\hskip 7.5pt}}cc}
    \toprule
    \multicolumn{11}{c}{Sample values: each line contains one entire beat)}\tabularnewline
    \midrule
    68.1 &72.8 &78.4 &85.6 &93.6  &98.1  &95.3  &91.2  &91.1 &... & \tikzmark{Top Mark}\tabularnewline
    74.4 &79.2 &85.6 &92.8 &100.8 &108.8 &115.2 &121.6 &     &... & \tabularnewline
    73.6 &77.6 &84.0 &91.2 &100.0 &108.8 &117.6 &124.8 &     &... & \tikzmark{Bottom Mark}\tabularnewline
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
  \InsertRightBrace[red, ultra thick]{Top Mark}{Bottom Mark}{Variable Length}
\end{document}
```

Comment: (+1) But a lot more work than changing `{` to `}`, though ;). Also `tikz` is a lot to load only for this and it requires multiple passes...

Comment: @cfr: Totally agree that it is overkill if you just one specific brace in solid black. But, sure comes in handy when you want to do any customizations.

Answer (score 6):

Here is an implementation that doesn't use [`bigdelim`](http://ctan.org/pkg/bigdelim); rather an `array` that is vertically aligned on the math axis:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{c c}
  \toprule
  Sample values: each line contains one entire beat \\
  \midrule
  $\left.\kern-\nulldelimiterspace \begin{array}{ *{9}{r} }
    68.1 & 72.8 & 78.4 & 85.6 &  93.6 &  98.1 &  95.3 &  91.2 & \ldots \\
    74.4 & 79.2 & 85.6 & 92.8 & 100.8 & 108.8 & 115.2 & 121.6 & \ldots \\
    73.6 & 77.6 & 84.0 & 91.2 & 100.0 & 108.8 & 117.6 & 124.8 & \ldots
  \end{array} \right\}$ \rlap{variable length} \\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular} 
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

With `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix` and it's built-in command `\SubMatrix`.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}
\begin{NiceTabular}{cc}
  \hline 
  Sample values: each line contains one entire beat) \\
  \hline 
  68.1 72.8 78.4 85.6 93.6 98.1 95.3 91.2 91.1 ... \\
  74.4 79.2 85.6 92.8 100.8 108.8 115.2 121.6 ... & \rlap{variable length} \\
  73.6 77.6 84.0 91.2 100.0 108.8 117.6 124.8 ... \\
  \hline 
\CodeAfter
  \SubMatrix{.}{2-1}{4-1}{\}}[extra-height=-1mm]
\end{NiceTabular} 
\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]