# mathtools brackets larger than \Bigg

Tags: delimiters, mathtools

I'd like to use the syntax of the `mathtools` package to generate brackets larger than `\Bigg.`

One can create larger brackets than `\Bigg` of specified size using

[About big parenthesis larger than Bigg](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6794/about-big-parenthesis-larger-than-bigg)

However, that solution doesn't work with the `\DeclarePairedDelimiter` construct of `mathtools.`

See the MWE below.  I suspect that what's needed is `\Vastl,` `\Vastr,` and `\Vastm` commands.

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage{mathtools}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\vast}{\bBigg@{4}}
\newcommand{\Vast}{\bBigg@{5}}
\makeatother

\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\parens}()

\begin{document}

\[
 \parens[\Bigg]{\dfrac{\dfrac{y}{x}}{\dfrac{a}{b}}}
\]

\[
 \Vast({\dfrac{\dfrac{y}{x}}{\dfrac{a}{b}}} \Vast)\qquad
 \parens[\Vast]{\dfrac{\dfrac{y}{x}}{\dfrac{a}{b}}}  % does not work
\]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, your suspicion  is right. Simply define:

```
\newcommand{\vastl}{\mathopen\vast}
\newcommand{\vastm}{\mathrel\vast}
\newcommand{\vastr}{\mathclose\vast}
\newcommand{\Vastl}{\mathopen\Vast}
\newcommand{\Vastm}{\mathrel\Vast}
\newcommand{\Vastr}{\mathclose\Vast}
```

and you can use `\vast` and `\Vast` with `\DeclarePairedDelimiter`.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage{mathtools}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\vast}{\bBigg@{4}}
\newcommand{\Vast}{\bBigg@{5}}
\newcommand{\vastl}{\mathopen\vast}
\newcommand{\vastm}{\mathrel\vast}
\newcommand{\vastr}{\mathclose\vast}
\newcommand{\Vastl}{\mathopen\Vast}
\newcommand{\Vastm}{\mathrel\Vast}
\newcommand{\Vastr}{\mathclose\Vast}
\makeatother

\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\parens}()

\begin{document}

\[
 \parens[\Bigg]{\dfrac{\dfrac{y}{x}}{\dfrac{a}{b}}}
\]

\[
 \Vast({\dfrac{\dfrac{y}{x}}{\dfrac{a}{b}}} \Vast)\qquad
 \parens[\Vast]{\dfrac{\dfrac{y}{x}}{\dfrac{a}{b}}}  % works now
\]
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: what's the meaning of the comment `% does not work` on the last example.  your output shows that it *does* work (and i have just reproduced that result).

Comment: that's just a hold over from my original