# Adjust delimiter size of big delimiters manually

Tags: delimiters

Often I find the delimiters that for example `\left(` and `\right)` produce too large.

I know about `\big`, `\Big`, `\bigg`, `\Bigg` to choose among the sizes

[image: delimiters]

but these are sometimes too small. `\left(` produces one like this:

[image]

How can I produce a shorter version of this extended delimiter (which is bigger than `\Bigg`)?

Comment: Have a look in the amsmath.sty source to see how they are defined. But it might also be an idea to rephrase if you feel you need manual delimiters larger than Bigg

Comment: @daleif What do you mean by "rephrase"? (Unfortunately I'm not able to make sense of the source code, which can be found [here](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/afs/cs/misc/tex/common/vendor/beta/lib/texmf/tex/amslatex/inputs/amsmath.sty), but there is no `\def\left` in there.)

Comment: That is not how big, Big, etc are defined, look them up instead. Rephrase, rewrite the math (assuming it is a math construction that needs this). Often it is more convenient to write: in order to simplify we define...., then...... For instance huge matrices, which can often be defined by smaller matrices making the huge matrix into say a 2x2 (where each entry might be a 6x6 matrix).

Comment: `\def\big{\bBigg@\@ne}
\def\Big{\bBigg@{1.5}}
\def\bigg{\bBigg@\tw@}
\def\Bigg{\bBigg@{2.5}}
\def\bBigg@#1#2{%
  {\@mathmeasure\z@{\nulldelimiterspace\z@}%
     {\left#2\vcenter to#1\big@size{}\right.}%
   \box\z@}}`

Copy/pasting the definition for `bBigg` doesn't work for me (I also did the `\makeat`[`letter`/`other`])...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [About big parentheses larger than Bigg](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/6794/69818).  **Edit:** Also see [mathtools brackets larger than \Bigg](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/262061/69818).

Comment: @GustavoMezzetti The possible duplicate answers my question.