# How do I make my nicefrac fraction line larger?

Tags: math-mode, fractions, nicefrac

I am trying to replicate this formula with LaTeX:

[image]

However, I am struggling to make the fraction look the same. This is my attempt:

```
\begin{equation}

\label{eq:alphaK}

\alpha(k) = \frac{1}{(N-k)} \nicefrac{ \left( \displaystyle \sum_{i=k+1}^{N} \lambda_i \right) }{\left( \displaystyle \prod_{i=k+1}^N \lambda_i \right)^{\frac{1}{N-k}}}

\end{equation}
```

Which results in the following:

[image]

I am looking for a way to increase the size of the "slash" (/) that separates the numerator and denominator. I know I could use a normal `\frac` instead of `\nicefrac` but I like how it looks when num/den are displayed side by side.

Is there any way I can force the fraction to look more like the first pictured one?

Comment: welcome to tex.se! please, always provide complete small document (beginning with `\documentclass` followed by necessary preamble and ending with `\end{document}`).

Comment: My apologies, I will do so in future

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are many ways. You will find two different in some variation below. The last one looks more like your desired output.

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{amsmath,xfrac,mathtools}

\begin{document}
\begin{align}
    \alpha(k) 
        &=\frac{1}{(N-k)} 
            \left.
                \left(\sum_{i=k+1}^{N} \lambda_i \right)
            \right/
            \left(\prod_{i=k+1}^N \lambda_i \right)^{\sfrac 1{(N-k)}}\label{eq:alphaK}\\
        &=\frac{1}{N-k} 
            \left.
                \left(\sum_{i=k+1}^{N} \lambda_i \right)
            \middle/
                \left(\prod_{i=k+1}^N \lambda_i \right)^{\frac 1{N-k}}
            \right.\\
        &=\frac{1}{N-k} 
            \biggl(\,\sum_{i=k+1}^{N} \lambda_i \biggr) 
            \bigg/ 
            \biggl(\,\prod_{i=k+1}^N \lambda_i \biggr)^{1/{(N-k)}}\\
            %space added as suggested by Enrico Gregorio
        &=\frac
            {\sum\limits_{i=k+1}^{N} \lambda_i}
            {(N-k)\, \sqrt[N-k]{\prod\limits_{i=k+1}^N\lambda_i}} 
        &\geq 1 \textup{ (by the AM–GM inequality)}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

**Remarks.**

- Please pay attention to *Zarko*'s comment.
- The nicefrac package might be replaced by https://ctan.org/pkg/xfrac.
- The question [mathtools brackets larger than \Bigg](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/262061/mathtools-brackets-larger-than-bigg) might be of interest for you.
- Another useful package is https://ctan.org/pkg/mathtools, look for the sections dealing with *delimiters.*
- Observe that I changed some aspects of the formula, which might collide with your notation.
- The video https://youtu.be/LFrdqQZ8FFc might also be helpful.

Comment: in your solutions you can omit `\displaystyle`  in both "fraction" terms. and if you use `align`, please add ampersands before equal signs.

Comment: @Zarko Right, I did not noticed that it was there.

Comment: +1, for considering my comment :-)

Comment: @DavidScott You are welcome.

Answer (score 4):

a small variation of [CampanIgnis](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/128553/campanignis) answer (since he was to fast for my frozen fingers :-( ):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nccmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}%\label{eq:alphaK}
\alpha(k) = \frac{1}{(N-k)}
            \left(\sum_{i=k+1}^{N} \lambda_i \middle)
            \!\middle/\!
            \middle(\prod_{i=k+1}^N \lambda_i \right)^{\mfrac{1}{N-k}}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Very nice :-)...for the frozen fingers.

Comment: @Zarko I then recommend you some お茶 for your fingers.

Comment: @Zarko I have a general question on your solution: If one of the products would be much, much larger then all other three delimiters would grow, too. Is that intentional?

Comment: @CampanIgnis, oh, it would be sufficient if I had a warm glove on my afternoon the walk :-).  about size of nominator and donominator: size is slašš line depends on taste. in such cases will rather use the following aproach: `\left(<nominator>\right)\left(<denominator>\right)^{-1}`