# How to get a nice brace of radicals in this expression?

Tags: math-mode, formatting

I am trying format this expression with some radicals.
I tried

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\[\left\{1,\sqrt{15},\sqrt{14+\sqrt{15}},\sqrt{14+\sqrt{14+\sqrt{15}}},\sqrt{14+\sqrt{14+\sqrt{14+\sqrt{15}}}}\right\}\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

If I use `Biggl` and `\Biggr`, I got

[image]

How to get a nice expression?

Comment: What is the problem with the first (the codes) output. Seems ok to me and there are no big possibilities of improvement. If you want even bigger brackets see this post: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/6796/120578

Comment: @koleygr yes, the question is vague. It is just that the nesting in general makes things look worse. OP, what exactly do you not like in the outputs above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does this solution with the `Bmatrix` environment befit you?

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\[ \begin{Bmatrix}
1,\sqrt{15},\sqrt{14+\sqrt{15}},\sqrt{14+\sqrt{14+\sqrt{15}}},\sqrt{14+\sqrt{14+\sqrt{14+\sqrt{15}}}}
\end{Bmatrix} \]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

As I said in my comment, if the need is bigger brackets use the answer of @LoopSpace from here:
https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/6796/120578

Then a code like:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\vast}{\bBigg@{4}}
\newcommand{\Vast}{\bBigg@{5}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
Yours:
\[\left\{1,\sqrt{15},\sqrt{14+\sqrt{15}},\sqrt{14+\sqrt{14+\sqrt{15}}},\sqrt{14+\sqrt{14+\sqrt{14+\sqrt{15}}}}\right\}\]

vast:
\[\vast\{1,\sqrt{15},\sqrt{14+\sqrt{15}},\sqrt{14+\sqrt{14+\sqrt{15}}},\sqrt{14+\sqrt{14+\sqrt{14+\sqrt{15}}}}\vast\}\]

Vast:
\[\Vast\{1,\sqrt{15},\sqrt{14+\sqrt{15}},\sqrt{14+\sqrt{14+\sqrt{15}}},\sqrt{14+\sqrt{14+\sqrt{14+\sqrt{15}}}}\Vast\}\]

\end{document}
```

Gives:

[image]

Comment: Please do not upvote as the question/answer seems to be a duplicate.

Comment: Huh? It doesn't matter whether it's duplicate, if the question and/or answer is good you upvote.  This site is very liberal about duplicates in contrast to, e.g. Stack Overflow.  Bad posts are also only downvoted for repeating offenders.

Comment: @HenriMenke, Yes, I knew... this is how I got 9,000... :P Just kidding. I usually if I find it is a duplicate I just vote to close, but in some cases that I feel that some more help than showing the duplicate is needed to the OP or if I am not sure if this is a duplicate (like in this case that I can no be sure what "nice brace" is supposed to mean)... I add an answer in which I don't want to steal real answers votes (I just copied some part of code from another person and then he will lose upvotes that I will take or that nobody will take because of my closed as duplicate answer)