# Error with ! Extra }, or forgotten \right

Tags: errors

Here is my latex code:

```
\begin{document}
\begin{align*} 
f_{Y_2}(y_2) &= \int_{\frac{1-\sqrt{2(-1+3y_2)}}{3}}^{1}\frac{1}{4\sqrt{R}} \mathrm{d}y_1 + \int_{0}^{1-\sqrt{-1+2y_2}}\frac{1}{4\sqrt{R}} \mathrm{d}y_1 \\
f_{Y_2}(y_2) &= \frac{1}{2\sqrt{3}} \left[\arcsin \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{\frac{1}{4} + \frac{3}{2}(y_2-\frac{1}{2})}} \right) - \arcsin \left(  \frac{-\sqrt{2(-1+3y_2)}}{2\sqrt{\frac{1}{4} + \frac{3}{2}(y_2-\frac{1}{2})}} \right) + \arcsin \left(\frac{1-\frac{3}{2}\sqrt{-1+2y_2}}{\sqrt{\frac{1}{4} + \frac{3}{2}(y_2-\frac{1}{2})}} -  \arcsin \left(\frac{-1}{2\sqrt{\frac{1}{4} + \frac{3}{2}(y_2-\frac{1}{2})}} \right) \right]
\end{align*}
```

Comment: You have an unclosed `\left`.

Comment: ... meaning that an `\right)` seems to be missing before the last `\arcsin`....

Comment: If you add to `\int` also `\limits` you certainly will have more space when you write the integranda function. See this example `\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article} \usepackage{mathtools} \begin{document} \[\int\limits_{\frac{1-\sqrt{2(-1+3y_2)}}{3}}^{1}\!\!\frac{1}{4\sqrt{R}}\] \end{document}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `\right` solves the problem. However, your equation is too wide, you need to break it, so you have to resize brackets manually instead of using `\left` and `\right`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\makeatletter % https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/6796/156344
\newcommand{\vast}{\bBigg@{3.5}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{align*} 
f_{Y_2}(y_2) &= \int_{\frac{1-\sqrt{2(-1+3y_2)}}{3}}^{1}\frac{1}{4\sqrt{R}} \mathrm{d}y_1 + \int_{0}^{1-\sqrt{-1+2y_2}}\frac{1}{4\sqrt{R}} \mathrm{d}y_1 \\
f_{Y_2}(y_2) &= \frac{1}{2\sqrt{3}} \vast[\arcsin \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{\frac{1}{4} + \frac{3}{2}(y_2-\frac{1}{2})}} \right) - \arcsin \left(  \frac{-\sqrt{2(-1+3y_2)}}{2\sqrt{\frac{1}{4} + \frac{3}{2}(y_2-\frac{1}{2})}} \right)\\
&\hphantom{={}}+ \arcsin \vast(\frac{1-\frac{3}{2}\sqrt{-1+2y_2}}{\sqrt{\frac{1}{4} + \frac{3}{2}(y_2-\frac{1}{2})}} -  \arcsin \left(\frac{-1}{2\sqrt{\frac{1}{4} + \frac{3}{2}(y_2-\frac{1}{2})}} \right) \vast)\vast]
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Sebastiano Well, this is for the OP.

Comment: Very good :-). +1 I have delete my previous comment and I have add the comment to the OP.