# Question about subfigure in Lyx

Tags: floats, lyx, subfloats

I tried to insert two side by side figures in IEEETRANS template. My document was compiled well when I used two minipages in a float, but I cannot get the captions (a) and (b) to be located right in the middle of these figures. Is there a way to solve this problem without using subfloat?

I tried to insert subfloats in a float to solve this problem, but my document cannot be compiled correctly. The errors include "You can't use \spacefactor in vertical mode", "Missing $ inserted", "Latex Error: Missing \begin{document}", and "Missing glyphs". How can I solve this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `You can't use \spacefactor in vertical mode"` means you have used some command such as `\@somecommand`  without using `\makeatletter` That would also generate a following `Missing \begin{document}` error

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I found if I remove the following definition:
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\vast}{\bBigg@{4}}
\newcommand{\Vast}{\bBigg@{5}}
\makeatother
my document can be compiled correctly. This definition is from the answer https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6794/about-big-parenthesis-larger-than-bigg, I am wondering why they are not compatible?

Comment: you used the definition in the wrong place, probably inside another definition, but no one can tell you what is wrong with your code if you do not show  it. But if your document works without the definition you are not using the command anyway.