# How to make a matrix with \langle and \rangle symbols?

Tags: matrices

I am interested in making matrices like this:

[image]

I have tried like this:

```
    \documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
    $\langle\mkern-1.5mu
    \begin{matrix}
        1\\2\\3
    \end{matrix}
    \mkern2mu\rangle
    $
\end{document}
```

which produces

[image]
How do I make a matrix with `\rangle` and `langle`?

Comment: use `\left\langle` etc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a basic element, `\left` and `\right` can be used to automatically adjust the size of delimiters such as brackets, braces etc. to the material in between. This also works with `\left\langle\begin{matrix}...\end{matrix}\right\langle`:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
$\left\langle
  \begin{matrix}
    1\\2\\3
  \end{matrix}
\right\rangle$
\end{document}
```

[image]

As can be seen in the image, the angles do not quite reach over the digits. This can be changed with the help of the [`yhmath` package](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/yhmath):

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{yhmath}
\begin{document}
$\left\langle
  \begin{matrix}
    1\\2\\3
  \end{matrix}
\right\rangle$
\end{document}
```

or just

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}% not needed in this case
\usepackage{yhmath}
\begin{document}
$\begin{amatrix}
    1\\2\\3
  \end{amatrix}$
\end{document}
```

Both result in:

[image]

If you like the angles of the `amsmath` example more, but also like the idea of a `amatrix` you can define it similar to, e.g., `bmatrix` from `amsmath.sty`:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\makeatletter
\newenvironment{amatrix}{\left\langle\env@matrix}{\endmatrix\right\rangle}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
$\begin{amatrix}
    1\\2\\3
  \end{amatrix}$
\end{document}
```

The result is the same as shown in the first example.

Note: Sometimes the size decision of `\left` and `\right` is not the best. In such cases using an explicit size with `\big`, `\bigg`, `\Big`, `\Bigg` can help, but for matrices [these sizes are very limited](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/6794/277964). But for matrices IMHO the sizes with `\left` and `\right` are mostly suitable.