# LaTeX commands for centering the equations without numbering them

Tags: horizontal-alignment, equations, numbering

What LaTeX commands should I use to center the equations on the page, but without numbering them?

Comment: Would this question help? http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1166/which-command-should-i-use-for-displayed-equations/

Comment: `\[1=1\]`  You may want to look at introductory guides such as the "not so short introduction to latex"

Answer (score 0):

You can use the environment `align*` of the package `amsmath`.
It centers the equations, and the `*` in the name prevents it to number the formulas.

Example :

```
\begin{align*}
f^* : ]0,+\infty[ &\rightarrow \mathbb{R}\\
m &\mapsto (m+1)e^m-me^m = e^m
\end{align*}
```