# Questions on basic LaTeX typesetting in mathematics

Tags: math-mode, horizontal-alignment, equations

I have one or two elementary questions on basic LaTeX typesetting:

1. I know putting `$$...$$` sign puts the mathematical expression in the middle (center), but what if I also want to center the mathematical expression as well as some (English) texts, say for example, I want to center the whole line

   ```
            We know $x^2\to 4$ as $x\to 2$.
   ```

   How do I center the whole English plus mathematics expression together in the middle of the page?
2. How do I write, using `$$...$$`, the following in LaTeX:

   ```
   (5) $lim_{x\to 2} x^2=4$
   ```

   Again I can center the part: `$lim_{x\to 2} x^2=4$`, but how do I number it together and the number does NOT get centered, but rather appears as I wrote above?

Comment: Please see http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503/5001 (and the associated answers) for a discussion of various reasons for *not* using `$$` in LaTeX documents. Incidentally, by using `$$ ... $$` (or `\[ ... \]`!), not only will the material be centered on a separate line, but the material will also be typeset in `\displaymath`-math style rather than in `\textstyle`-math.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 4):

Without PSTricks.

[image]

```
\documentclass[preview,border=12pt]{standalone}%please replace it with \documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
    We know that $f(x)\to f(a)$ as $x\to a$ but
\end{center}
\begin{equation}
    \lim_{x\to a}f(x) \not\to f(a)
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Note: for left aligned equation number, use `leqno` (stands for **left equation number**) option passed to the class. I mean `\documentclass[leqno]{article}`, for example.

Comment: -1 for not using TikZ.                                                                                                                                                                                                                              ;-)

Answer (score 4):

Using `$$...$$` is considered bad practice, in LaTeX. You should use `\[...\]` for display math instead. See [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1166/which-command-should-i-use-for-displayed-equations/1180#1180) for a discussion on which commands should be used for display math in LaTeX.

1. You can use [Karl's student solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/105634/21891), or mine. If the two equations meant to go together, it's best to put them in a common `gather` environment (see Barbara Beeton's comment on that below). `\notag` is used to suppress an equation number locally.
2. Passing the class option `leqno` puts all equation numbers on the left-hand side, rather than on the right-hand side, of the equations.

EDIT (following barbara beeton's comment):

```
    \documentclass[leqno]{article}
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \begin{document}
    \begin{gather}
        \text{We know $x^2 \to 4$ as $x \to 2$.} \notag\\
        \lim_{x\to2} x^2=4
    \end{gather}
    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Where do people get this "bad practice" idea from?  Knuth designed TeX with $ signs and it works just fine with $ signs.  Some of us still use and like plain Tex.  It's more flexible, easier to understand, and better documented (in the TeX Book).

Comment: For more insight on why `\[...\]` is preferable to `$$...$$` in LaTeX, see [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1166/which-command-should-i-use-for-displayed-equations/1180#1180).

Comment: @Thruston Problem is amsmath and LaTeX not with Knuth:) `$$..$$` environment
leads to centred equations even with the global option `fleqn` (f orce left equations). `texdoc onlyamsmath`. So if one does not use this option can safely use it.

Comment: @Thruston The question is dealing with LaTeX, where it *is* definitely bad practice using `$$`. Of course this has nothing to do with its usage in Plain TeX.

Comment: i won't comment on the use of `\[...\]` vs. `$$`, but it *is* bad practice to string separate one-line display equations together.  instead, it's better to choose a "grouped" style; here, i'd use `gather` (from `amsmath`) since there's no need for alignment.  equation numbers can be suppressed on lines where they're not needed with `\notag`, and extra space between lines added with the `\\[<dimen>]` option.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Whether the OP wanted to write those display equation back to back is unclear, hence my use of two separate display-math environments. However, to promote better practice for subsequent visitors, I've modified my answer in accordance with your comment.

Answer (score 3):

this answer requires

```
\usepackage[leqno]{amsmath}
```

since both lines are centered, without any need for alignment, i'd choose the `gather` environment, and suppress the number from the first line with `\notag`:

```
\begin{gather}
 \text{We know } x^2\to 4 \text{ as } x\to 2 \notag \\
 \lim_{x\to 2} x^2=4
\end{gather}
```

note that the spaces around the text inclusions need to be included explicitly within the `\text{...}` argument, or explicit math spaces used.

the `amsmath` users guide is highly recommended.  `texdoc amsldoc` at a command line on a tex live system.