# How to draw a cyclic sequence in latex

Tags: arrows, tikz-arrows

```
  $$a_0 \to a_1 \to a_2 \to ....... \to a_k  $$
```

Right now, I want to draw a curved  directed arrow that goes from `$a_k$` to `$a_0$`

Is there any way to do that ?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is  `tikzmark` library for this. You can make one handmade macro yourself too.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand{\tikzmark}[3][]{\tikz[remember picture,baseline] \node [inner xsep=0pt,anchor=base,#1](#2) {#3};}

\begin{document}
  \[\tikzmark{a}{$a_0$} \to a_1 \to a_2 \to \dots \to \tikzmark{b}{$a_k$} \] 
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \draw[->] (a.north east) to[bend left] (b.north west);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

To make it cyclic, some thing like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand{\tikzmark}[3][]{\tikz[remember picture,baseline] \node [inner xsep=0pt,anchor=base,#1](#2) {#3};}

\begin{document}
  \[\tikzmark{a}{$a_0$} \to a_1 \to a_2 \to \dots \to \tikzmark{b}{$a_k$} \]
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \draw[->,rounded corners=1ex] (b.east) -| ++(2ex,2ex)  to[bend right,looseness=1] ([shift={(-2ex,2ex)}]a.west) |- (a.west);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is `thick` necessary? Actually, I think it's wrong. Also the random dots should be `\dots`

Comment: @egreg Right, changed, :-)

Comment: Can one modify this so the arrow goes from $a_k$ starts of to the right, then loops around and approaches $a_0$ from the top or left?  (So as to make the diagram appear more cyclic.  BTW the OP asked for the arrow in the other direction--from mark $b$ to $a$.)

Comment: @Kimball: not a problem.

Answer (score 4):

The following solution with TikZ works without `\tikzmark` and additional LaTeX run for remembering positions. The arrow head of the curved arrow matches the default appearance of LaTeX's `\rightarrow` or its synonym `\to`. Also the start of the error uses a round line cap. Parameter `looseness` is used to flatten the curve a bit to reduce the vertical space requirements of the curved arrow:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usetikzlibrary{bending}
\usetikzlibrary{topaths}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[
    baseline=(a0.base),
    inner sep=0pt,
    line cap=round,
    >={Computer Modern Rightarrow[bend]},
  ]
    \node (a0) {$a_0$};
    \node[anchor=base west] (a1) at (a0.base east)
      {${}\to a_1 \to a_2 \to \dots \to{}$};
    \node[anchor=base west] (ak) at (a1.base east)
      {$a_k$};
    \draw[
      ->, 
      transform canvas={yshift=.3em},
    ] (ak) to[bend right, looseness=.6] (a0);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result with smaller looseness setting]

**Remarks:**

- Do not use `$$` for displayed equations in LaTeX, see [Which command should I use for displayed equations?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1166/16967)
- `inner sep=0pt` avoids additional white margins around the nodes.
  `yshift` is used to move the curved arrow a bit to the top to get more distance between the arrow start and end to the corresponding math symbols. An alternative approach would be the use of options `shorten <` and `shorten >`.
- The empty `{}` in math mode as in `{} \to a_1` make an empty math atom for the proper spacing around `\to`.

Answer (score 3):

Second solution shows how to do this without usage of TikZ. Only pdfTeX primitives are expected.

```
{\lccode`\?=`\p \lccode`\!=`\t  \lowercase{\gdef\ignorept#1?!{#1}}}
\def\usedim#1 {\expandafter\ignorept\the#1 \space}

\def\cyclicseq#1{\setbox0=\hbox{\kern-.7em$#1$\kern-.7em}%
    \dimen0=.3\wd0 \dimen1=.7\wd0
    \leavevmode \kern.7em
    \pdfsave\pdfsetmatrix{.9397 .342 -.342 .9397}\raise4pt\rlap{$\prec$}\pdfrestore
    \pdfliteral{q .9963 0 0 .9963 0 7 cm .4 w 0 0 m
        \usedim\dimen0 10 \usedim\dimen1 10 \usedim\wd0 0 c S Q}%
    \vbox to15pt{}\box0 \kern.7em
}

Text $\cyclicseq{a_0 \to a_1 \to a_2 \to \ldots \to a_k}$ text.
```

[image: cycle]