# Use matrices in TikZposter environment?

Tags: tikz-pgf, matrices, tikzposter

I am trying to create a poster using TikZposter. I would like to have some math involving matrices in my poster. When I do:

```
\documentclass{tikzposter}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usetheme{Default}
\begin{document}
\block{My Block}{
 Some text\\
 \begin{align*}
   M+A=T+H
 \end{align*}
}
\end{document}
```

everything works fine, but as soon as I try to include a matrix:

```
\documentclass{tikzposter}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usetheme{Default}
\begin{document}
\block{My Block}{
 Some text\\
 \begin{align*}
   \begin{matrix}
   M & A \\
   T & H
   \end{matrix}
 \end{align*}
}
\end{document}
```

MikTex complains with over a hundred error messages and does not generate an output. Am I doing something wrong? How can I fix this? Will I have to avoid using matrices all together? Thanks for any suggestion!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't say why, but as an alternative you can use `array`. Note that you should never use `\\` before a displayed math environment (such as `align`, `equation` and `gather`), and for single line equations you generally don't want to use `align`/`align*`, but `equation`/`equation*` (see [align vs equation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/321/align-vs-equation) and [Which command should I use for displayed equations?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1166/which-command-should-i-use-for-displayed-equations)).

```
\documentclass[a2paper]{tikzposter}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usetheme{Default}
\begin{document}
\block{My Block}{
 Some text
 \begin{equation*}
   \begin{array}{cc}
   M & A \\
   T & H
   \end{array}
 \end{equation*}
With delimiters:
 \begin{equation*}
 \left(  \begin{array}{cc}
   M & A \\
   T & H
   \end{array}
  \right)
 \end{equation*}
}
\end{document}
```