# Vertical spaces around display math

Tags: spacing, macros

*(First of all, I know that `\[ \]` should be used instead of `$$ $$` and I do it.)*

I'd like to know about the vertical spacing around math display blocks.

According to `texdef -t latex \[` we have

```
\[:
macro:->\relax \ifmmode \@badmath \else \ifvmode \nointerlineskip \makebox [.6\linewidth ]{}\fi $$\fi
```

and `texdef -t latex \]` returns

```
\]:
macro:->\relax \ifmmode \ifinner \@badmath \else $$\fi \else \@badmath \fi \ignorespaces
```

So I didn't see any command for vertical spacing.

Since the command `$$` appears in the code above I tried also `texdef -t tex $$` and `texdef -t latex $$` with no success.

If I'm not wrong I remember something related with `\abovedisplayskip` or something similar.

**Well, my question is:** Are the vertical spaces above and below the command `\[ \]` the same as the ones inserted by `\begin{equation}\end{equation}` (and its stared versions)? How to check this reading the macros and codes?

Comment: this has been asked before, eg http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30909/abovedisplayskip-vs-abovedisplayshortskip  or http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18180/uneven-display-skips/18183#18183

Comment: The short answer to your question is no, longer answer  http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/503/why-is-preferable-to/69854#69854 (and somewhere I have an answer with examples, but I don't see it now)

Comment: OK, thanks David. Let's close the post, if necessary.

Comment: Up to you, although all the links I posted were failed attempts to find an answer of mine that I'm sure is there somewhere (but perhaps it was on comp.text.tex last century, hard to be sure:-)

Comment: I just voted to close this as the duplicate as suggested above.