# AMS Split inside AMS Align

Tags: amsmath, align

I'd like to have multiple lines inside a single align cell like so:

```
\begin{alignat*}{1}
= & \begin{split}x+\\
y\end{split}
\end{alignat*}
```

But I get an error like:

```
 \end{alignat*}

\An extra & here is so disastrous that you should probably exit
 and fix things up.
```

What's the correct way to achieve this?

Comment: Why do you want to use `split` inside `alignat`?

Comment: I am showing a series of steps in modifying an equation and one of the steps produces a very long expression which I'd like to wrap around.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I don't know what you are trying to achieve. Your error message can be bypassed if you either increase the number of reference points in the `alignat`

```
\begin{alignat*}{2}
= & \begin{split} x+ \\
y\end{split}
\end{alignat*}
```

or if you use `aligned` instead of `split`

```
\begin{alignat*}{1}
= & \begin{aligned} x+ \\
y\end{aligned}
\end{alignat*}
```

With `split`, it tries to anchor its `&` to line up with the ones outside (so multiple `split`s inside one `equation` will line up). So implicitly you need one extra reference point if you use `split` inside `alignat`, which is just a glorified array. (I'm doing a horrible job explaining this, am I not?) `aligned` doesn't try to do that (two `aligned` blocks inside one `equation` won't line up), and so you can get by with just one reference point.

In anycase, either of this sets the broken expression `x+y` as one unit to the right, vertically centered, against the `=` sign, which I suspect may not be what you want. If you want the `=` to line up with the `x+` and with the `y` in a line below, you should take Lev's suggestion.

Comment: Thank you for explaining the previously mysterious error message!

Answer (score 16):

It's not clear what effect you're trying to achieve, but it is certainly possible to use `split` inside `align`, for example:

```
\begin{align}
  x &= a+b\\
  \begin{split}
  y &= a - b\\
    &\quad +c-d\\
    &\quad +e+f
  \end{split}\\
  z &= e-a
\end{align}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly the effect I wanted to achieve. Unfortunately, LyX's instant preview is incorrect for this, but it does render correctly.

Comment: It works but it seems to have a problem if you use a second ampersand or double ampersands for additional alignment.

Comment: @Konstantin any fix found?

Answer (score 0):

maybe that will help ... 2 columns and 4 equations but only 3 are numbered (2 of them got 1 number between them)

```
\begin{align}
  x &= a+b &x &=b\  \begin{split}
  y &= a - b\\
    &\quad +e+f
  \end{split}
    &
  \begin{split}
  x &= a - b\\
    &\quad +e+f
  \end{split}  \  z &= e-a &x &=b
\end{align}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Perhaps you could improve your answer to show to what extent it differs from [Lev Bishop's answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/3768/5872)?