# Problem with using multline and align

Tags: errors, equations, align, multline

I am LaTeX begginer and when I run this equation, I am getting the error:

```
! Argument \align* has an extra {.
```

Here is the equation.

```
\begin{multline}
\begin{align*}
C_s & = \displaystyle \max_{P(g_M)} \int_0^{\infty} 
        \bigg[ \left(1-\exp\left(-\frac{g_M}{\overline{g}_W}\right) \right)
            \log\left(1+\frac{g_MP(g_M)}{N_M}\right)- \\
            \int_0^{g_M} \log\left(1+\frac{g_WP(g_W)}{N_W}\right)
            \frac{1}{\overline{g}_W}\exp\left(-\frac{g_W}{\overline{g}_W}\right)
        dg_W \bigg] 
        \frac{1}{\overline{g}_W}\exp\left(-\frac{g_M}{\overline{g}_M}\right) dg_M \\ 
    & = \max_{P(g_M)} \int_0^{\infty} 
        \bigg[\log \left(1+\frac{g_MP(g_M)}{N_M}\right) -
            \exp\left(\frac{1}{\overline{g}_WP(g_M)}\right)
            \bigg(Ei\left(\frac{1}{\overline{g}_WP(g_M)}\right)- \\
                  Ei\left(\frac{g_M}{\overline{g}_W}+
                  \frac{1}{\overline{g}_WP(g_M)}\right)
            \bigg)
        \bigg]
        \frac{1}{\overline{g}_M}\exp\left(-\frac{g_M}{\overline{g}_M}\right) dg_M 
\end{align*}
\end{multline}
```

Can someone please help?
Thank in advance

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, then they're marked as a code sample. You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button ({}) or select your code and hit Ctrl+K.

Comment: I have edited your code to make it more legible. Why are you using `multiline` and `align` at the same time? It seems like you are missing alignment characters (ampersands `&`).

Answer (score 4):

This is probably close enough to what you are trying to achieve:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
\begin{split}
C_s & = \max_{P(g_M)} \int_0^{\infty} 
        \bigg[ \left(1-\exp\left(-\frac{g_M}{\overline{g}_W}\right) \right)
            \log\left(1+\frac{g_MP(g_M)}{N_M}\right) \\
    &\quad -\int_0^{g_M} \log\left(1+\frac{g_WP(g_W)}{N_W}\right)
            \frac{1}{\overline{g}_W}\exp\left(-\frac{g_W}{\overline{g}_W}\right)
        dg_W \bigg] 
        \frac{1}{\overline{g}_W}\exp\left(-\frac{g_M}{\overline{g}_M}\right) dg_M 
\end{split}\\ 
\begin{split}        
    & = \max_{P(g_M)} \int_0^{\infty} 
        \bigg[\log \left(1+\frac{g_MP(g_M)}{N_M}\right) 
            -\exp\left(\frac{1}{\overline{g}_WP(g_M)}\right)
            \bigg(Ei\left(\frac{1}{\overline{g}_WP(g_M)}\right) \\
    &\quad   -Ei\left(\frac{g_M}{\overline{g}_W}
                      +\frac{1}{\overline{g}_WP(g_M)}\right)
            \bigg)
        \bigg]
        \frac{1}{\overline{g}_M}\exp\left(-\frac{g_M}{\overline{g}_M}\right) dg_M 
\end{split}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

A couple of points:

- It is perfectly ok to use `split` inside `align` (see for instance [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3767/ams-split-inside-ams-align)).
- You should put the minus signs after line breaking.
- You don't need `displaystyle` as equations are already displayed in the `align` environment.
- You can improve the alignment by adding white space with `\quad`, `\qquad` or even `\phantom`.

Comment: I wouldn't even use split, no need. Just ={}& and &-

Comment: In this case you are right, there is no need to use `split` but the advantage I see in using it is that if we were using `align` then `split` would automatically take care of the tag, whereas otherwise you have to do it manually.