# Why should I ever use equation when I can always use align?

Tags: math-mode, equations, best-practices

Is there any reason why I should use `equation` when I `align` seems to produce the same output?

The reason I am asking is that I like solving math using LaTeX. Sometimes I write a single equation using the `equation` environment, but later realise I need to include more equations aligned to the first in that same environment. Then I need to change the

```
\begin{equation}
\end{equation}
```

to

```
\begin{align}
\end{align}
```

and include the `&`s as appropriate.

I am thinking then: why not always use align, maybe even including the `&` before the equal sign, just in case I need to include more stuff there later? If they behave the same, and one is more flexible, why use the other at all? Or are there differences and reasons why I should avoid using `align` when there is a single equation?

Comment: Check the [Short Math Guide for LaTeX](ftp://ftp.ams.org/pub/tex/doc/amsmath/short-math-guide.pdf) it may help.

Comment: @cmhughes yes, it is a duplicate. Cheers  :)

Comment: The abovementioned link for the Short Math Guide is dead.  [Use this one instead.](https://mirror.ctan.org/info/short-math-guide/short-math-guide.pdf)

Answer (score 15):

Say you want to split equations, then you need to use `equation+split` and align can't be used with split.

**EDIT:** This MWE shows why `align` can not be used to split an equation and `split` should be used.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
%-------------------------------------------------
We use \verb|split| with \verb|\equation| environment to split this equation:
%=============================
\begin{equation}\label{eq:grscope4}
  \begin{split}
      \Delta p_{x} &= \left[ {\left( {\frac{h}{\lambda }\sin \alpha } \right)
                         - \left( { - \frac{h}{\lambda }\sin \alpha } \right)} \right]
                         + \left( {\frac{h}{\lambda }\sin \alpha } \right)\\[4pt]
                   & \phantom{==} - \left( {\frac{h}{\lambda }\sin \alpha } \right)
 \end{split}
\end{equation}
%=============================
The number comes at the center of two equation.

We use \verb|align| to split the equation now:
%=============================
\begin{align}
\Delta p_{x} &= \left[ {\left( {\frac{h}{\lambda }\sin \alpha } \right)
                         - \left( { - \frac{h}{\lambda }\sin \alpha } \right)} \right]
                         + \left( {\frac{h}{\lambda }\sin \alpha } \right)\\[4pt]
                   & \phantom{==} - \left( {\frac{h}{\lambda }\sin \alpha } \right)
\end{align}
%=============================
We get two numbers. To suppress one of them we say \verb|\nonumber|,
see the difference below:
%=============================
\begin{align}
\Delta p_{x} &=  \left[ {\left( {\frac{h}{\lambda }\sin \alpha } \right)
                         - \left( { - \frac{h}{\lambda }\sin \alpha } \right)} \right]
                         + \left( {\frac{h}{\lambda }\sin \alpha } \right)\\[4pt]
                    & \phantom{==} - \left( {\frac{h}{\lambda }\sin \alpha } \right) \nonumber
\end{align}
%=============================
The \verb|\nonumber| is not effective in the first line where we wanted to suppress the number. 
Instead it works in the last line only. Hence equation numbering becomes a mess.
%-------------------------------------------------
\end{document}
```

[image]

If the equation has to be split in more than two lines this situation worsens further if one is using `align`.

**Conclusion** `equation` can not be completely sacrificed for `align`.

Comment: I had never heard of `equation+split`. I will look it up...

Comment: It seems to me the main issue is spacing. It makes a big difference to use `equation` instead of `align`, as explained in the duplicate question linked above.

Comment: @Vivi That is true. since it is discussed in the link, I did not mention. I will try to provide a MWE for split later today.

Comment: the question is going to be closed as a duplicate, and in any case I googled and I think I understand (you can get one number in the center when using split)

Comment: @Vivi: The [`amsmath` documentation](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/amsmath/amsldoc.pdf) has some nice examples on how to use split and other environments. I actually use it more than align these days, and you can use multiple splits in one equation, allowing some quite elaborate stuff.

Comment: @Vivi, That is right. I think now it is clear.

Comment: @Vivi, See the MWE.

Comment: My first use of split today  :)

Comment: @Harish Kumar: Nice answer - unfortunately the question is closed. Will you copy it to http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/321/align-vs-equation , where no one else has made that point.

Comment: @Hans-PeterE.Kristiansen: Thanks for the kind words. I have added a link to the question you mentioned. `:-)`

Comment: @GarbageCollector Just wanted to push things little towards right so that `-` comes after the bracket. Only personal taste.

Comment: you can use \notag instead and the number will come out correctly in the align environment

Comment: You can do the same trick using align + aligned.

Comment: Why do you say that align doesn't work with split? The documentation clearly states that it does.