# How to split optimisation problem over two lines?

Tags: equations, line-breaking, breqn

I have this expression involving minimisation. How do I split it over two lines? The problem is \min seems to be separated from the objective function. **breqn** does not seem to work, as this is not an *equation*.

```
$$\min_{\substack{A,B,\\ 0\le A\le T \\ D+X+W-S\ge 0}}\bigg(I+X+W-E,-(X+k(A-B))\bigg)$$
```

Comment: is `\min\bigg(I+X+W-E,-(X+k(A-B))\bigg)_{\substack{A,B,\ 0\le A\le T \ D+X+W-S\ge 0}}` acceptable?

Comment: I have never seen an opti. problem posed like that. But in case, I am constrained in horizontal space, so that doesn't work.

Comment: Why do you have a comma in the function to be minimized?

Comment: @percusse: It is multivalued objective function - two functions minimised simultaneously over common constraint space.

Comment: @Shyam Sorry for my ignorance about it. I was suspecting that but I couldn't understand how you can do that without a functional e.g. how do you order `(1,2)` and `(2,1)`. I know it's not related to TeX at all but just out of curiosity :) You can also bash me [in our chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41) if you feel like it

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you need to break up the conditions of the minimization problem across two or more lines, the following will work:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
  \min_{\substack{A,B\\ 0\le A\le T \\ 
     D+X+W-S\ge 0}}
  \Bigl(I+X+W-E-\bigl(X+k(A-B)\bigr)\Bigr)
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want the minimization conditions to be spread over just two lines, replace the first `\\` with `;\` and you'd get:

[image]

**Addendum**, posted after receiving a clarification from the OP: If, rather, the objective is to break up the *argument* of the minimization problem (I must confess I'd overlooked the comma in the earlier MWEs), the following should be of interest:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\setlength\textwidth{2in} % simulate a narrow column
\begin{document}
\begin{multline*}
  \min_{\mathclap{\substack{A,B\\ 0\le A\le T \\ D+X+W-S\ge 0}}}
     \big(I+X+W-E,\\[-5ex]
     X+k(A-B)\big)
\end{multline*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: With the first way, one can also insert a negative space before the objective function, so as to shift it nearer "min". Avoiding the parentheses' growth would render this quite nicely.

Comment: Thanks @Mico, but this is not what I am looking for. I have a 1-column space in a 2-column write-up. Is it possible to split the two obj. functions appropriately? The constraints are not the problem, as I have enough vertical space.

Comment: This is nice, but the matrix is elevated compared to the min and that makes it awkward.

Comment: OK, I made another modification -- now using the `multline` environment rather than the `pmatrix` environment. Hope this meets your needs.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your efforts, @Mico. This is *exactly* what I had wanted :)

Comment: The mathclap in there is kind of dangerous though. Here it works, but if you take a larger brace (e.g. `\bigg`), it might protrude into the text set under `min`. Is there actually a way to fix something like that? For example by pushing the text down a bit?

Comment: @mSSM -- Sadly (or happily?!!), *very few* TeX macros are completely safe. :-) I deliberately chose `\big` rather than `\Big` as the modifier for the opening parenthesis so that there wouldn't be a clash. If you did need to move the first line ("A,B") down a bit, you could do so by inserting something like `\\[1ex]` (or whatever amount is required) right before `A,B`; of course, you'd then have to increase the negative adjustment after `-E,` by the same amount -- in the present example from `\\[-5ex]` to `\\[-6ex]`.

Comment: @Mico --- right, thanks. That's the easiest solution. I recently ran into a similar problem, and messing with raiseboxes and vphantoms was rather messy... :)

Answer (score 5):

Refining Mico's answer according to your comment: You can use an `alignat` environment to set the equation in two rows and two columns. Each row's third `&` defines the alignment position, while `\notag` and `\\[-2em]` ensure that (1) there is just one equation number and (2) that in spite of the height of the cell containing `min`, the lines are not overly spaced.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{alignat}{2}
  &\min_{\substack{A,B\\ 0\le A\le T \\ 
     D+X+W-S\ge 0}}
     &\bigg(I+X &+W-E,\notag\\[-2em]
  &  &          &-(X+k(A-B))\bigg)
\end{alignat}
\end{document}
```

**Addendum:**

As @mSSM pointed out in a comment, the `equation` environment is superior to `alignat` when it comes to determining the space between the equation and surrounding paragraphs. It may therefore be desirable to use the `alignedat` (note the **ed**) *subsidiary* environment inside an `equation` environment, as depicted in the second figure below. Note the centered placement of the equation number.

[image]

[image]

The second figure's code:

```
\begin{equation}
\begin{alignedat}{2}
  &\min_{\substack{A,B\\ 0\le A\le T \\ 
     D+X+W-S\ge 0}}
     &\bigg(I+X &+W-E,\\[-2em]
  &  &          &-(X+k(A-B))\bigg)
\end{alignedat}
\end{equation}
```

Comment: If you want to typeset only one equation, it is better to use `\begin{alignedat}` inside a `\begin{equation}` environment. Also, the `\qquad` can be replaced by a simple `{}`.

EDIT: Geez this was ugly; removed my rewrite, because it looked messed up as a comment.

Comment: Ah, sure. Initially I had the second row not aligned but indented, that's where the `\qquad` came from. Why is it superior to place `alignedat` inside an `equation`?

Comment: For one, it makes more sense. :) If you only typeset one equation (even if it happens to be on several lines), then you shouldn't use an environment which is made for typesetting several equations.

Also, you don't have to put \notags everywhere (less clutter).

And last but not least, the equation environment is "more powerful" than align:
http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/325/6993

Comment: Thanks @dgs, this seems the closest to what I had hoped for. Will wait for some more comments/answers before accepting.

Comment: @mSSM Thanks for pointing me at the spacing issue; I've wondered about that a few times but wasn't aware it's a feature.

Answer (score 2):

If you are having freedom to change styles, my suggestion is to reduce cluttering parameters inside the main equation. Here are the different possibilities:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
%
\begin{document}
 \textbf{version - 1:}
\[\min_{\substack{A,B;\ 0\le A\le T \\ D+X+W-S\ge 0}}\bigg(I+X+W-E,-(X+k(A-B))\bigg)\]

\textbf{version - 2:}
\[\min_{\substack{A,B}}\bigg(I+X+W-E,-\big(X+k(A-B)\big)\bigg) \qquad \text{ subject to } 0\le A\le T \text{  and  } D+X+W-S\ge 0\]

\textbf{version - 3:}
\[\min_{\substack{A,B}}\bigg(I+X+W-E,-\big(X+k(A-B)\big)\bigg) \]
subject to
\[0\le A\le T\]
\[D+X+W-S\ge 0\].
\end{document}
```

[image]

You may try to split parameters more meaningfully and the equation becomes more readable IMO.