# How to prevent additional vertical space around tall inline equations

Tags: spacing, equations, line-spacing

I've got a Figure caption with a couple of short inline equations in it, one of which being `$\psi_\text{pseudo}$`, and because of the subscript + descender, LaTeX inserts additional space between this line and the next. However, the next line is also the last and only a third filled, so it doesn't get near the subscript anyway -- and even if it did, I'd prefer to have even line-spacing.

So: how can I prevent LaTeX from increasing the line-spacing after the inline equation?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx).

Comment: Just a guess -- if you don't necessarily need a `figure` for your equations, you could set them inside a subsidiary equation environment, and `equation` would take some care of the vertical spacing (see e.g. the addendum to [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/57303/14697) or [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/58158/14697), where spacing to the upper paragraph can be, and indeed _is_ decreased). If the comments so far don't help, please provide [some code](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that).

Answer (score 5):

TeX inserts some vertical space to ensure text elements don't overlap. For these special cases, you could consider using `\smash` - this removes all vertical box lengths (height and depth) from its argument. So, you would use `\smash{$\psi_\text{pseudo}$}`, say.

Left shows the original, right shows the output when using `\smash` (Click to enlarge):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\caption{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
Pellentesque cursus odio cursus leo tempus auctor. Quisque 
porttitor diam ac urna bibendum a hendrerit sem auctor. 
Vestibulum dictum congue tincidunt. In tortor neque, ullamcorper 
nec ultrices eu, vulputate eu enim. Suspendisse vulputate 
aliquam est a volutpat. Integer ut nisl sem. Phasellus sit 
amet metus mi, nec consectetur mauris. Suspendisse potenti. 
Curabitur gravida libero nulla. Quisque at nunc sit amet 
risus ullamcorper rhoncus at at dui \smash{$\psi^2_\text{pseudo}$}. 
Nunc leo odio, vestibulum eu mattis ut, gravida in leo~$x^2$.}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Note though that any changes in the paragraph layout might cause problems in the paragraph flows differently.