# eqnarray or equation for single-line equations?

Tags: equations, best-practices

Normally I would use `\begin{equation}`, of course. But I got a huge file (more than two hundred pages) where many equations are formatted like this:

```
\begin{eqnarray}
  a = b + 1 % no & here!
\end{eqnarray}
```

AFAICT the visual difference is minimal. Still, should I convert all this to `\begin{equation}`?

(I suspect that the bigger problem might be the missing `&` characters around the `=`. If I add them, I get exactly the same output as with `\[...\]`, which should be the right thing.)

I use the svmono document class, if that is important.

Comment: Please see: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/196/eqnarray-vs-align

Comment: @MarcoDaniel Thanks, but that question is about a list of related equations, which I don't have here.

Comment: Use `equation` for single line equations (or `\[...\]` for unnumbered ones) and *never ever* use `eqnarray`.

Comment: @egreg: It seems to me your comment answers this question. Maybe you should put it as an answer!?!

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/321/align-vs-equation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `equation` for single line equations (or `\[...\]` for unnumbered ones) and **never ever** use `eqnarray`. See [eqnarray vs align](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/196/eqnarray-vs-align) for more information.

Comment: This suggests that I convert all equations. However, the link and the documents linked from it and the answers do not seem to give any information for my specific question: **single** line, **no** alignment (i.e. no `&`). No source says anything bad (or good) about that (unless I missed something). So while your answer certainly is good general advice, I am not sure how it applies here.

Comment: @WolframH If you don't want to edit your document, fine. But you'll do yourself a favor using the right environment for each equation or group thereof. This doesn't include `eqnarray`. :)