# Specify alignment per column in align equation

Tags: horizontal-alignment, vertical-alignment, amsmath, align

Using the following mwe i have not yet found a way to align the formulas correctly.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}  % extends amsmath and fixes some of its quirks
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}


\begin{align}\label{eq:mergefunction_with_weighting}
\curlyvee(v, \omega) := 
l_1 \triangleright l_2 = 
\left\{
 \begin{aligned}
       &l_1(v)               &                          &\text{wenn $v \in G_1 \setminus G_2$}\\
\omega(&l_1(v)) + (1-\omega)(&\hat{R}l_2(v) +\hat{t})   &\text{wenn $v \in G_1 \cap G_2$}\\
       &                     &\hat{R}l_2(v) +\hat{t}    &\text{wenn $v \in G_2 \setminus G_1$}.
 \end{aligned}
\right.
\end{align}


\end{document}
```

My output is currently like this:

[image]

Everything is fine except the vertical and horizontal alignment/spacing within the `aligned` environment. But in that you can notice the following:
 - First `&` works fine.
 - The second `&` should be aligned to
   `\hat{R}` and without spacing between the `(` and the `\hat{R}` in
   the middle row 
 - At the last `&`, the spacing in the middle row between
   `\hat(t))` and `wenn` should be larger. (I think this one would disappear as soon as the second `&` is fixed.

So the requests i have sum up to the question: Whats the best and consistent way to approach placement issues like these?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your output is what you'd expect from `aligned`: you have four columns, the 1st and 3rd right aligned, the 2nd and 4th left aligned, and some space between the first and the second "lr pair". What you actually want is best achieved with a `cases` environment; `@{}` is used where you don't want space between the columns.

[image: output]

Note that the vertical space between the lines is smaller than with your `aligned` code. If you want the same vertical spacing as with `aligned`, use `\\[\jot]` instead of `\\` in the code below.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}  % extends amsmath and fixes some of its quirks
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}\label{eq:mergefunction_with_weighting}
  \curlyvee(v, \omega) := l_1 \triangleright l_2 = 
  \left\{
    \begin{array}{@{}r@{}l@{}ll}
       &l_1(v)               &                          &\text{wenn $v \in G_1 \setminus G_2$}\\
\omega(&l_1(v)) + (1-\omega)(&\hat{R}l_2(v) +\hat{t})   &\text{wenn $v \in G_1 \cap G_2$}\\
       &                     &\hat{R}l_2(v) +\hat{t}    &\text{wenn $v \in G_2 \setminus G_1$}.
    \end{array}
  \right.
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

You can also use `\begin{cases}...\end{cases}` instead of `\left\{...\right.`, but then in this particular example the equation number doesn't fit anymore. Moreover, note that there's no need to use `align` as the outer environment since that one has no tab stops; I'd use `equation` instead.

Comment: if id use a cases construct, it would only change the source code of the "outer" part. the inner part would need to stay as an array like you posted, correct?

Comment: See my edit: is that what you meant?

Comment: yeah! thanks. I havent found equation that works with an `equation` but not with `align` environment. Thats why i stick to `align` per default...

Comment: @helt: See also [align vs equation](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/321).

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `cases` environment and `\phantom` to achieve the desired alignments

```
\[
\curlyvee(v, \omega) := 
l_1 \triangleright l_2 = 
\begin{cases}
\phantom{\omega(}l_1(v) &   \text{wenn $v \in G_1 \setminus G_2$}\\
\omega(l_1(v)) + (1-\omega)(\hat{R}l_2(v) +\hat{t})   &\text{wenn $v \in G_1 \cap G_2$}\\
\phantom{\omega(l_1(v)) + (1-\omega)(}\hat{R}l_2(v) +\hat{t} &\text{wenn $v \in G_2 \setminus G_1$}.
\end{cases}
\]
```

A second option is to use a `tabbing` environment inside a `minipage`

```
\[
\curlyvee(v, \omega) :=  l_1 \triangleright l_2 = 
\begin{cases}
  \begin{minipage}{0cm}
    \begin{tabbing}
      $\omega($\=$l_1(v)) + (1-\omega)($\=$\hat{R}l_2(v)+\hat{t})$ \quad\= \kill
      \> $l_1(v)$ \>\>   wenn $v \in G_1 \setminus G_2$\\
      $\omega(l_1(v)) + (1-\omega)(\hat{R}l_2(v) +\hat{t})$ \>\>\> wenn $v \in G_1 \cap G_2$\\ 
      \>\> $\hat{R}l_2(v) +\hat{t}$ \> wenn $v \in G_2 \setminus G_1$.
    \end{tabbing}
  \end{minipage}
\end{cases}
\]
```

Comment: thanks. Would you mind telling me which package is providing `\phantom` and its documentation?

Comment: and isnt there another way of doing this? Setting invisible text seems to be a source for typing errors

Comment: @helt `\phantom` is provided by TeX.

Comment: could split both answers as they look like completely different approaches to me?

Answer (score 2):

I think you want to use the `alignedat` environment instead of `aligned`.  This is similar to the `aligned` environment in that it provides pairs of `r`/`l` equations, but without the inter equation space that the `aligned` environment adds. So the only changes required to your code as posted above are:

1. Replace the `\begin{aligned}` with `\begin{alignedat}{4}`, and the corresponding `end{}`.
2. Change the second and third alignment point from `&` to `&&`.  This doubling changes the alignment from `r`ight aligned to `l`eft aligned which is what you want.
3. Change `text{wenn...}` to `text{ wenn...}`, or use `\quad\text{wenn...}` instead so that you have some space there.

[image]

### Notes:

- But as the other solutions mention, the outed environment really is a `cases` (or `dcases`) environment and should *not* be an `align` as you do not have multiple equations that are aligned. You have *one* equation.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}  % extends amsmath and fixes some of its quirks
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}


\begin{align}\label{eq:mergefunction_with_weighting}
\curlyvee(v, \omega) := 
l_1 \triangleright l_2 = 
\left\{
 \begin{alignedat}{4}
       &l_1(v)               &&                          &&\quad\text{wenn $v \in G_1 \setminus G_2$}\\
\omega(&l_1(v)) + (1-\omega)(&&\hat{R}l_2(v) +\hat{t})   &&\quad\text{wenn $v \in G_1 \cap G_2$}\\
       &                     &&\hat{R}l_2(v) +\hat{t}    &&\quad\text{wenn $v \in G_2 \setminus G_1$}.
 \end{alignedat}
\right.
\end{align}


\end{document}
```