# Is any downside in using align instead of \[...\]?

Tags: align

Is any downside in always using the align environment? I.e, if I use

```
\begin{align}
a&=b
\end{align}
instead of
\begin{equation}
a=b
\end{equation}
and
\begin{align*}
a&=b
\end{align*}
instead of
\[
a=b
\]
```

would I see a difference in output?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Yes, there are downsides; never use `align` for one liners.

Comment: If you're interested in learning more about various display-math environments (and, in the process, figuring out for yourself an answer to the question you've posted), I would like to suggest you follow the discussion at http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/40531/5001.

Comment: good question, but I'd say this is a duplication of [align vs equation](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/321)