# Equation number in an array

Tags: math-mode, equations

I want to put the equation number at the right for the following code:

```
\[
 \log{y_{i}} = 
\left\{
  \begin{array}{l l}
    y_{2i}^{*} & \quad \textrm{if $y_{2i}^{*}\succ0$}\\
    0 & \quad \textrm{otherwise}
  \end{array} 
    \right.
    \]
```

Any idea?

Comment: Do you want the individual elements in the `array` numbered, or the equation as a whole?

Comment: I want the equation as a whole.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Do wisely use `{}` to maintain readability.

```
\documentclass[preview,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\abovedisplayskip=0pt\relax% don't use this line in your production
\begin{equation}
\log y_i= 
\begin{cases}
    y_{2i}^* & \quad \text{if $y_{2i}^*\succ0$}\\
    0 & \quad \text{otherwise} 
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Metrics: It is not the alternative solution but the correct one. `align` is used when you have more than one equation to be aligned.

Comment: @Metrics: Please read [align versus equation](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/321/align-vs-equation).

Comment: `flalign` should not be used in this case.

Answer (score 3):

load package `amsmath` and then replace `\[ ... \]` by

```
\begin{flalign}
...
\end{flalign}
```