# Enumerating tikz-cd diagrams

Tags: numbering, tikz-cd

How can I enumerate diagrams made with tikz-cd?

I mean, not only enumerate them but enumerate in order to quote them later in the document.

Comment: Insert them inside an equation as you do with simple formulas.

Comment: @Sigur But that leaves much space between the last text line and the begin of the diagram.

Comment: Don't leave any blank line on your code before/after the `equation` environment.

Comment: You'll have to define some diagram environment with a counter of its own. Then I think you can even corss-reference them smartly with the `cleveref` package.

Comment: Do you want just a number (as for a standard `equation`) or do you want something more elaborate as a caption (name+number+separator+description)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You just use the standard `equation` environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,tikz-cd}

\usepackage{lipsum}% just to have some text
\begin{document}

\lipsum*[2]
\begin{equation}\label{diagram}
\begin{tikzcd}
A\arrow[r,"f"] \arrow[d,"\alpha"] & B \arrow[d,"\beta"] \\
A' \arrow[r,"f'"] & B'
\end{tikzcd}
\end{equation}
\lipsum*[3]
\begin{equation}\label{equation}
A+B+C=D
\end{equation}
some text after the equation just to see the spacing and
for printing the references to diagram~\eqref{diagram}
and to equation~\eqref{equation}.

\end{document}
```

[image]

I can see excess spacing nowhere.

Comment: For some reason, you really have to use `equation` and not `align`. Using `align` causes all sorts of alignment issues.

Comment: @Umang You should use `align` only for multiline displays. If you have an actual problem with diagrams in `align`, please ask a new question.

Comment: I didn't know that `equation` is more semantically correct that `align` for single line equations. I posted my comment just as a warning for anyone who (like me) uses `align` for all equations. [Apparently I've been doing this wrong](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/321/align-vs-equation).