# Incorrect spacing after minus sign with combination of amsmath and hyperref

Tags: math-mode, hyperref, amsmath

When no packages are loaded, no space is inserted after the minus sign of a negative number:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
  -1 = -1 % output: -1 = -1
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

However, when both amsmath and hyperref are used, a space is inserted in the negative number which starts the content of an `equation` environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
  -1 = -1 % output: - 1 = -1
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

In the latter example, the minus sign seems to be treated as subtraction instead of negative.

How can I get the same result as the former example when the two packages are loaded?
I've found that `align` environments do not have this problem,
but I hear that [using `align` instead of `equation` is bad](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/321/44901).

Output example with for the second case:

[image: minusone]

Comment: good catch, it appears you have found an `hyperref` bug.

Comment: and there is also an `amsmath` bug with the `multline` environment, which manifests itself as in your `MWE`,  although it does not have the same cause (being present without `hyperref`). See my [answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/235715/4686) for proposed patches.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

*edit adds a patch to another, pure amsmath,  problem; see bottom of answer*

Not an easy one. First of all indeed `hyperref` should always be loaded after `amsmath` because it does things depending on whether `amsmath` is loaded, but does not delay this to `At Begin Document`.

The problem of a unary minus is already taken care of by `hyperref`'s redefinition of `\equation` (code comment near lines `7553` of hyperref.pdf)

> `\mathopen` is needed in case the equation starts with an unary minus, for example.

but this redefinition is done only if `amsmath` is not loaded. In the case `hyperref` detects `amsmath` it modifies the `amsmath` definition in a different way, moving the `\refstepcounter` and ensuing `hyperlink` business to the start of the formula, to avoid putting things in the surrounding vertical list. However it appears that `hyperref` forgot in that case to also add the `\mathopen` thing.

Here is a proposed patch.

**not tested in any thorough way** *it would be better to get hyperref to patch only equation etc...*

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
% always load hyperref after amsmath
\usepackage{hyperref}
\makeatletter
\def\hyper@refstepcounter#1{%
  \edef\This@name{#1}%
  \ifx\This@name\name@of@eq
    \@ifundefined{theHequation}{%
      \make@stripped@name{\theequation}%
      \let\theHequation\newname
    }{}%
  \fi
  \HyCnt@ProvideTheHCounter{#1}%
  \hyper@makecurrent{#1}%
  \ifmeasuring@
  \else
  %%  \ifmmode\mathopen\bgroup\fi  %% first version of the patch (line I)
    \Hy@raisedlink{%
      \hyper@anchorstart{\@currentHref}\hyper@anchorend
    }%
  %%  \ifmmode\egroup\fi           %% first version of the patch (line II)
  \fi
  \ifmmode\mathopen{}\fi           %% second version: THIS LINE ADDED IN PATCH
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
  -1 = -1 % output is now OK
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

A similar problem non-related to `hyperref` exists in `amsmath`, with the `\multline` environment, as pointed out in comments. I can propose the following patch, with no guarantee as this is a job for someone who knows all the innards of amsmath already.

The patches are done with the help of `etoolbox`.

*about this patch I am not sure why `amsmath` has `\displaystyle{}` and not `\displaystyle` alone which would not create the problem; an alternative patch would be to simply replace `\displaystyle{}` by `\displaystyle`, but there might be some reason for the `\displaystyle{}` (compare the `\shoveleft` definition in `amsmath.sty`).*

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

% un deuxième problème a émergé qui n'est pas lié à hyperref.

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\begin{document}\thispagestyle{empty}

Before the patch:
\begin{multline}
    -1 = -1\\ -2 = -2
\end{multline}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd
{\multline@}{\displaystyle{}}{\displaystyle{}\mathopen{}}
   {\typeout{multpatch SUCCESS}}
   {\typeout{multpatch FAILURE}}

\patchcmd
{\mmeasure@}{\displaystyle{}}{\displaystyle{}\mathopen{}}
   {\typeout{mmpatch SUCCESS}}
   {\typeout{mmpatch FAILURE}}

\makeatother

After the patch
\begin{multline}
    -1 = -1\\ -2 = -2
\end{multline}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This should be done also when `\ifmeasuring@` is true or the lengths will be computed in a wrong way. Why not simply adding `\mathopen{}` after the trailing `\fi`?

Comment: @egreg The location of `Hy@raisedlink` in the false branch is the original location from `hyperref.sty`.

Comment: Well, it doesn't matter, does it?

Comment: @egreg Perhaps, but I wasn't into adventuring into other modifications; could not exclude the hyperref authors had their reasons. I have modified the proposed patch, adding the `\mathopen{}` after the conditional.

Comment: @egreg The reason I was into making the hyperlink of type mathopen is because this is what `hyperref.sty` does with its non-amsmath redefinition of `\equation`. However it is indeed simpler to put `\mathopen{}` after it. The box of zero width and height inserted by `hyperref` being of type `ord`.

Comment: I understand the philosophy. Unfortunately, the patch doesn't fix `multline`.

Comment: @egreg The `multline` similar issue is unrelated to `hyperref`. This is a pure `amsmath` problem.

Comment: Then a simpler fix might be adding `\mathopen{}` at the end of `\equation`.

Comment: @egreg See edited answer for `\multline` problem.

Comment: @krnk Yes. But a fix by Heiko would be better.

Answer (score 8):

Force the unary minus to be of type `\mathord` either via `\mathord{-}`, or `{-}`:
[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,hyperref}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
  {-}1 = -1 % output: -1 = -1
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Most likely this stems from [`hyperref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref)'s insertion of content at the start of the horizontal list for (hyper-) referencing. As such the first `-` is treated as a binary operator. The bracing reverts it back to the view that resembling the unary operator.

Comment: It's interesting that this problem occurs with the `equation` and `multline` environments, but not with the `align` and `gather` environments. I would assume (though I can't prove it) that this is a bug in `hyperref`.

Comment: @Mico It doesn't happen for the alignment environments, because the stepping of the `equation` counter doesn't happen at the start of the (sub)formulas, which are typeset as cells in a `\halign`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use eqnarray instead of equation!
It solves your problem. :)

```
\begin{eqnarray}
  -1 = -1 % output: -1 = -1
\end{eqnarray}
```

Comment: While this is a valid solution, [`eqnarray` is less than ideal](http://goo.gl/3R7Ln) in general.