# How do I use equation in this scenario without running into "Missing number, treated as zero"

Tags: equations, align

I'm pretty new to Latex and I am working with a bunch of formulae. I'd like to give each of them different numbering and this is what I've got:

```
\begin{align}
\begin{split}
 &|\Theta_P| = {|P| \choose 2} \land P \not= \emptyset
\end{split} \\
\begin{split}
 & \forall D_n \in \Theta_P \\
 & \qquad \left(d_n,\delta_n\right) := D_n \\
 & \qquad\qquad |d_n| =2\\
 & \qquad\qquad d_n\in \mathcal{P}(P)\\
 & \qquad\qquad |\delta_n| = 2 \\
 & \qquad\qquad \bigcup \delta_n = P \setminus d_n \\
 & \qquad\qquad \bigcap \delta_n = \emptyset \\
  \end{split} \\
 \begin{split}
  & \forall D_n, D_m \in \Theta_P \\
 & \qquad \left(d_n,\delta_n\right):= D_n \\
  & \qquad \left(d_m,\delta_m\right):= D_m \\
 & \qquad\qquad d_n=d_m \iff D_n=D_m \\
\end{split} 
\end{align}
```

It is working good.

[image: works]

However, after [some read-up](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/321/81426) I figured perhaps I should be using equation for my formulae instead of align. But when I changed `align` to `equation` above I run into this error:

> Missing number, treated as zero

and it mentioned something about `\relax \end{split} \\`.

I tried removing the `\\` between split blocks but it would make the 3 formulae aligned horizontally, which is not what I want.

Why am I running into this error and what should I do to use `equation` in this scenario?

Comment: In that case you shouldn't use `equation` I think. `gather` might be more appropriate than `align` though, you're not aligning the three splits.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Ohh, thanks for the suggestion. But should I try to keep my syntax as consistent as possible? I used `equations` most of the times since it helps to squeeze the symbols together.

Comment: The first `split` is redundant; you shouldn't have ``\\`` before `\end{split}`. Also `{|P|\choose 2}` should be `\binom{|P|}{2}`. Note that `equation` is wrong and `align` is right.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `equation` environment is for single line (or single `split`) equations; in this case you do need `align`.

The first `split` is redundant and `\\` before `\end{split}` should be omitted. Also `\choose` should not be used with `amsmath` and

```
\binom{|P|}{2}
```

is the correct syntax.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{align}
 &|\Theta_P| = \binom{|P|}{2} \land P \not= \emptyset
\\
\begin{split}
 & \forall D_n \in \Theta_P \\
 & \qquad (d_n,\delta_n) := D_n \\
 & \qquad\qquad |d_n| =2\\
 & \qquad\qquad d_n\in \mathcal{P}(P)\\
 & \qquad\qquad |\delta_n| = 2 \\
 & \qquad\qquad \bigcup \delta_n = P \setminus d_n \\
 & \qquad\qquad \bigcap \delta_n = \emptyset
\end{split} \\
\begin{split}
 & \forall D_n, D_m \in \Theta_P \\
 & \qquad (d_n,\delta_n):= D_n \\
 & \qquad (d_m,\delta_m):= D_m \\
 & \qquad\qquad d_n=d_m \iff D_n=D_m
\end{split} 
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

I also removed the redundant `\left`–`\right` pairs.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I propose one of these variants.I replaced `:=` with `\coloneqq` form `mathtools` to have a vertically centred colon w.r.t. the axis  of the = sign:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{alignat}{2}
  &\mathrlap{\lvert\Theta_P\rvert = \binom{\lvert P\rvert}{2} \land P \not= \emptyset}\\[1.5ex]
    & \forall D_n \in \Theta_P & \quad & \begin{aligned}[t] & (d_n,\delta_n) \mkern-2mu\coloneqq D_n \\
  & \lvert d_n\rvert =2\\
  & d_n \in \mathcal{P}(P)\\
  & \lvert\delta_n\rvert = 2\\
  &\bigcup \delta_n = P \setminus d_n \\
  & \bigcap \delta_n = \emptyset
  \end{aligned}\\[1.5ex]
    & \forall D_n, D_m \in \Theta_P & \quad & \begin{aligned}[t] & (d_n,\delta_n) \mkern-2mu\coloneqq D_n \\
  &(d_m,\delta_m) \coloneqq D_m\\
  & d_n= d_m \iff D_n=D_m
  \end{aligned}
\end{alignat}

\begin{alignat}{2}
  &\mathrlap{\lvert\Theta_P\rvert = \binom{\lvert P\rvert}{2} \land P \not= \emptyset}\\[1.5ex]
    & \forall D_n \in \Theta_P & \quad & \begin{aligned}[t] \renewcommand\arraystretch{1.25}\begin{array}[t]{|@{\hskip0.6em}l}
  (d_n,\delta_n) \mkern-2mu\coloneqq D_n \\
  \lvert d_n\rvert =2\\
  d_n \in \mathcal{P}(P)\\
  \lvert\delta_n\rvert = 2\\
  \bigcup \delta_n = P \setminus d_n \\
  \bigcap \delta_n = \emptyset
  \end{array}
  \end{aligned}\\[1.5ex]
    & \forall D_n, D_m \in \Theta_P & \quad & \begin{aligned}[t] \renewcommand\arraystretch{1.25}\begin{array}[t]{|@{\hskip0.6em}l}
  (d_n,\delta_n) \mkern-2mu\coloneqq D_n \\
  (d_m,\delta_m) \coloneqq D_m\\
  d_n= d_m \iff D_n=D_m
  \end{array}
  \end{aligned}
\end{alignat}

\end{document}
```

[image]