# New line in equation

Tags: equations, line-breaking

I have such code:

```
\begin{equation*}
        max_X (min_{\vec{Y}} F(X, \vec{Y})) = sup_{X} (inf_{\vec{Y}} F(X, \vec{Y})) = \Gamma_1, \newline
        min_{\vec{Y}} (max_X F(X, \vec{Y})) = inf_{\vec{Y}} (sup_{X} F(X, \vec{Y})) = \Gamma_2        
    \end{equation*}
```

How I set a break line? `\\` doesn't work too.

Comment: related information: [align vs equation](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/321/579)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example, `gather*` can be used instead of `equation*` with package `amsmath`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{gather*}
  \max\nolimits_X \min\nolimits_{\vec{Y}} F(X, \vec{Y})) =
  \sup\nolimits_{X} (\inf\nolimits_{\vec{Y}} F(X, \vec{Y})) = \Gamma_1, \\
  \min\nolimits_{\vec{Y}} (\max\nolimits_X F(X, \vec{Y})) =
  \inf\nolimits_{\vec{Y}} (\sup\nolimits_{X} F(X, \vec{Y})) = \Gamma_2
\end{gather*}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]