# pmatrix with \left( \frac \right)

Tags: amsmath, matrices, delimiters

The following MWE results in the Matrix shown in the picture. I would like the braces of the cos- and sin-functions in the first column not to touch each other. How can I achieve that?
[image]

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document
\begin{align}
^{V}\boldsymbol{T}_{L}=
\begin{pmatrix}
cos\left(\frac{\pi\delta_i}{180}\right) & -sin\left(\frac{\pi\delta_i}{180}\right)  & 0 \\
sin\right(\frac{\pi\delta_i}{180}\left) & cos\left(\frac{\pi\delta_i}{180}\right)   & 0 \\
0                            & 0                                   & 1 
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

Comment: the easiest thing to do is add just manually add a bit of space after the first row:  `... \\[3pt]`.  be sure not to leave any space before the `[3pt]`, or it will get printed instead of being interpreted as a space.  (`amsmath` checks that.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For such small fractions, I recommend just `\bigl` and `\bigr`, instead of `\left` and `\right`, which would choose `\Big` size that's too large. There's no need to cover all symbols in between.

You can increase the separation between rows with `\\[1ex]` or so.

Always use `\sin` and `\cos` for the functions; also I added `bm` that's recommended for `\boldsymbol` (and can be abbreviated in `\bm`). Also, I lowered the subscript by adding an empty superscript. The “prescript” is better preceded by `{}` (although in this case it wouldn't matter). Finally, don't use `align` for single equations.

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{amsmath,bm}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
{}^{V}\boldsymbol{T}^{}_{L}=
\begin{pmatrix}
\cos\bigl(\frac{\pi\delta_i}{180}\bigr) & -\sin\bigl(\frac{\pi\delta_i}{180}\bigr)  & 0 \\[1ex]
\sin\bigl(\frac{\pi\delta_i}{180}\bigr) & \cos\bigl(\frac{\pi\delta_i}{180}\bigr)   & 0 \\[1ex]
0                                       & 0                                         & 1
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your efforts! But now I got a couple of new questions: 1. What does the bm-package do? 2. Why not use align for single equations?

Comment: by the way: the empty superscript thing is awesome!

Comment: @Max For the `align` question, spacing and semantics, see e.g. [align vs equation](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/321)

Comment: @Max `bm` realizes `\boldsymbol` in a much better way. Vertical spacing is better with `equation` when a single formula is to be displayed. The empty superscript is an old trick that comes in handy several times: for instance if you have `$a_{i}b_{i}^{2}$` the subscripts would be misaligned; with `$a^{}_{}ib_{i}^{2}$` they are at the same level.

Comment: ok, thanks a lot guys. I will consider using equation.  
@egreg about the bm: Can I just load the package and it will not possibly destroy anything in my document? I'm very close to finishing my thesis and i don't want to mess anything up now.

Comment: and another small question: would you suggest using \arctan or \tan^{-1}?

Comment: @Max In this case it's better not to touch the code; you could make an experiment, if you have time. About `\tan^{-1}` I have a strong opinion: never. `;-)` I know that it *should* be interpreted as the inverse function but there are two reasons why it's wrong: (1) the tangent function is not (globally) invertible; (2) `\tan^2` had been used for more than a century before the `^{-1}` notation for an inverse function came into use. Similarly the arcsine is the inverse function of a suitable restriction of the sine function, so `\sin^{-1}` is abusive too.

Comment: well, to face the problem of none-global-invertibility, i originally defined an atan2-function like the one matlab uses. But I was told that it doesn't matter and I should not mention it. But your argument is still valid and I will use \arctan so!

Answer (score 2):

Since you load the `array` package, there is another method for slightly increasing row height of the matrix automatically. You just add `\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}` within your environment to increase the height by about 20%. I agree with egreg on the rest of changes he made.

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{amsmath,bm}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}

\begin{align}\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
^{V}\boldsymbol{T}^{}_{L}=
\begin{pmatrix}
\cos\bigl(\frac{\pi\delta_i}{180}\bigr) & -\sin\bigl(\frac{\pi\delta_i}{180}\bigr) & 0 \\
\sin\bigl(\frac{\pi\delta_i}{180}\bigr) & \cos\bigl(\frac{\pi\delta_i}{180}\bigr)  & 0 \\
0                                       & 0                                        & 1 
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image]