# expression below argmax

Tags: math-mode, amsmath, math-operators

In some places in my document I have used the following (and it works quite well):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmax}{argmax} % thin space, limits underneath in displays

\begin{document}

\[z = \argmax_x f(x)\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

However, when I try to use something like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmax}{argmax} % thin space, limits underneath in displays

\begin{document}

    \begin{tabular}{c l}
        $z = \argmax_x f(x)$ \\
        $z = \argmax_{x \in \mathcal{X}} f(x)$
    \end{tabular} 

\end{document}
```

It does not work anymore. It seems that `tabular` is somehow to blame here.

[image]

UPDATE2:
Well, it was clearly because I was using inline math ($). Thanks David!

Comment: please always post a complete document that shows the problem. I made a complete document as in the answer below but it is not clear what the issue is?

Comment: well of course, you have used inline math there `$` so get the inline form not the display layout. and it applies to both cases so the "works" "not works" in the original part of the question is misleading

Comment: if you want aligned _display_ use an enviornment for that such as `align` not `tabular`

Comment: I will edit so it is clearer. Thanks! Could you update your answer with a short example using aligned? that would be awesome!

Comment: see this answer for reasons why TeX sets limits to the side in inline math https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/323367/i-have-a-question-about-the-displaystyle-command/323375#323375

Comment: I hope it makes more sense now

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[image]

It isn't clear what you mean by "not work" the output is as I expect.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmax}{argmax} % thin space, limits underneath in displays

\begin{document}



a
\[z = \argmax_x f(x)\]

b
\[z = \argmax_{x \in \mathcal{X}} f(x)\]

\end{document}
```

---

Updated question shows it is just an issue of display or inline setting:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmax}{argmax} % thin space, limits underneath in displays

\begin{document}



a
\[z = \argmax_x f(x)\]

b
\[z = \argmax_{x \in \mathcal{X}} f(x)\]

a2
$z = \argmax_x f(x)$

b2
$z = \argmax_{x \in \mathcal{X}} f(x)$


a3 (don't do this)
$z = \argmax\limits_x f(x)$

b3 (or this)
$z = \argmax\limits_{x \in \mathcal{X}} f(x)$


c
\begin{align*}
z &= \argmax_x f(x)\\
z &= \argmax_{x \in \mathcal{X}} f(x)
\end{align*}




\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks david! I was expecting exactly that! There is likely something else going on in my document. I will try to reproduce the problem in a small doc.

Comment: @purpleTentacle answer updated

Answer (score 11):

Try using `\underset{belowtext}{text}`.

Note below that:

- `\mathrm` is for using non-italics Roman font in math mode.
- `\,` is for adding a thin space

```
z = \underset{x}{\mathrm{argmax}}\, f(x)
```

[image]