# Centering columns in xtabular with multicolumn and multirow

Tags: tables, multirow, multicolumn

I've been trying to create a table that could go between two pages. I've looked at the `longtable` package but does not work well with `twocolumn`. So I decided to take a look at the `xtabs` package and seems to be the one for me.

I have a table with 4 columns (I'm doing one to list some costants). The first one
contains the symbol, the second one the name, the third the value and the last one the unit of measure. My problem lies in the second and in the fourth one.

What I would like to have is a style of the columns that is a centered both vertically and horizontally. I'm using this style: `c >{\centering}p{1.8cm} c p{1.5cm}`. I'm not really achieving what I would like in any of them.
[image: The result]
As you can see, the first column is not centered vertically unless I'm using a `\multirow` call and the last column is not centered. If I try and replicate the style of the second one, I get
[image: error]
with several errors all saying `Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr. &`

This is the "working" MWE

```
\documentclass[8pt, a4paper, twocolumn]{extarticle}

\usepackage{extsizes}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,mathtools,calrsfs}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{xtab, booktabs, array}

\everymath{\displaystyle}

\renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{2}

\begin{document}
\section{Costanti}

\tablefirsthead{\toprule Simbolo& Nome & Valore & Unità di misura \\ \midrule}
\tablehead{Simbolo& Nome & Valore & Unità di misura \\ \midrule}
\tablelasttail{\bottomrule}

\begin{center}
    \begin{xtabular}{c >{\centering}p{1.8cm} c p{1.5cm}}
            $g$ & Accelerazione gravitazionale & $9.81$ & $\frac{\text{m}}{\text{s}^2}$\\ \hline
            $G$ & Costante di Gravitazione Universale & $6.67\cdot10^{-11}$ & $\frac{\text{Nm}^2}{\text{kg}^2}$\\\hline
            \multirow{5}[1]{*}{$p_{atm}$} & \multirow{5}[1]{1.8cm}{Pressione atmosferica} & $1$ & $\text{atm}$\\
                        && $1.01\cdot10^{5}$ & $\text{Pa}$\\ 
                && $760$ & $\text{mm}\,\text{Hg}$\\
                && $1.01\cdot10^{5}$ & $\frac{\text{N}}{\text{m}^2}$\\
            $N_A$ & Numero di Avogadro & $6.02\cdot10^{23}$ & /\\ \hline
            $V_m$ & Volume occupato da Gas in STP & $22.4$ & $\text{l}$\\ \hline
            \multirow{2}[1]{*}{$R$} & \multirow{2}[1]{1.8cm}{Costante universale dei Gas} & $0.0821$ & $\frac{\text{l}\cdot\text{atm}}{\text{nK}}$\\
            && $8.31$ & $\frac{\text{J}}{\text{nK}}$\\ \hline
                && $1$ & $\text{bar}$\\ \hline
            \multirow{2}[1]{*}{$c_{H_2O}$} & \multirow{2}[1]{1.8cm}{Calore specifico dell'acqua} & $4.186\cdot10^3$ & $\frac{\text{C}}{\text{kg}\cdot\text{K}}$\\
                && $1$ & $\frac{\text{cal}}{\text{g}\cdot\text{K}}$\\\hline
            $\lambda_f$ & Calore di fusione dell'acqua & $3.335\cdot10^5$ & $\frac{\text{J}}{\text{Kg}}$\\\hline
            $\lambda_v$ & Calore di vaporizzazione dell'acqua & $2.257\cdot10^6$ & $\frac{\text{J}}{\text{Kg}}$\\\hline
    \end{xtabular}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

The other one just changes the definition of the table to `\begin{xtabular}{c >{\centering}p{1.8cm} c >{\centering}p{1.5cm}}`

My question now is: how can I get the results I want while maintaining the `twocolumn` and the table that goes to the other page? I would like to have the columns centered both vertically and horizontally inside a table that can span multiple pages/columns.

Thanks for any answers.

Comment: eek don't do `\everymath{\displaystyle}`

Comment: I'm quite sure that it is not the problem here. Is just an easier way for me to typeset the whole document (the actual one is much bigger) and I prefer using display style even inside text.

Comment: no it's unrelated to the table (for that you probably just want to use `m` rather than `p` and `\centering\arraybackslash`) but see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/323375/1090

Comment: Oh I see. Thanks for the link. And yes! It worked! I had also to change a bit the `multirow` definition but I can manage. I'll add this as an answer for others to see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to David Carlisle in the comments, I got it to work.

Basically just needed to change the definition of the table to `\begin{xtabular}{c >{\centering\arraybackslash}m{1.8cm} c >{\centering\arraybackslash}m{1.5cm}}`. That centered everything like I wanted.

I also added a `\centering` inside the  `multirow` environment to make it all nice. This is the result
[image: Workin]