# Make \lim be multi line instead of single line

Tags: positioning

I am using this to represent a limit:

```
\lim _{b\rightarrow \infty }
```

But the limit expression gets on the side of the lim symbol.

[image]

I want it to be under lim.

I see that in some LaTeX represented versions, it appears in a correct way.

I use the following packages:

```
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[osf,slantedGreek]{mathpazo}
```

Comment: `\lim\limits_{b\to\infty}`.  But are you sure you *really* want it?

Comment: Outside of a math environment `$\displaystyle \lim_{b \rightarrow \infty}$` should do what you want.

Comment: @GuM Thank you, I could go without it, I guess I want it because I am used to see it in this way and it looks more aesthetic to me.

Comment: @epR8GaYuh Thank you. This makes me wonder what an environment is in LaTeX, gotta research.

Comment: you could do as the comments above say but note this completely breaks the intention of inline math layout which is not to disturb the line spacing of the paragraph. If you need that layout it is better to use a display math construct such as `\[...\]`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thank you David. Did not know the fact that this happens in order to keep stuff in the line. I thought it was just a "style fact", like fonts. Now I understand the point. Hope this does not make it a useless question for the community anyways. All the best.

Comment: you ask specifically about `\lim` but is i suppose more generally a duplicat eof this one: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/323367/i-have-a-question-about-the-displaystyle-command/323375#323375

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The textstyle layout is designed not to disturb the interline spacing in the surrounding paragraph.  If you force the use of limits style on math operators, or worse, force the use of displaystyle for the whole inline expression, the line spacing is disturbed and it is hard to see the paragraph as a unit of text. If the expression is complicated enough to require this, it is better to set it using a display construct such as `\[\]` rather than inline.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}


\begin{document}

\section{inline textstyle}
The cat sat on the mat. The cat sat on the mat. The cat sat on the mat. 
The cat sat on the mat. The cat sat on the mat. The cat sat on the mat. 
$\lim_{b\to-\infty} \frac{x}{b} = ?$
The cat sat on the mat. The cat sat on the mat. The cat sat on the mat. 
The cat sat on the mat. The cat sat on the mat. The cat sat on the mat. 


\section{inline textstyle with limits}
The cat sat on the mat. The cat sat on the mat. The cat sat on the mat. 
The cat sat on the mat. The cat sat on the mat. The cat sat on the mat. 
$\lim\limits_{b\to-\infty} \frac{x}{b} = ?$
The cat sat on the mat. The cat sat on the mat. The cat sat on the mat. 
The cat sat on the mat. The cat sat on the mat. The cat sat on the mat. 

\section{inline displaystyle}
The cat sat on the mat. The cat sat on the mat. The cat sat on the mat. 
The cat sat on the mat. The cat sat on the mat. The cat sat on the mat. 
$\displaystyle\lim_{b\to-\infty} \frac{x}{b} = ?$
The cat sat on the mat. The cat sat on the mat. The cat sat on the mat. 
The cat sat on the mat. The cat sat on the mat. The cat sat on the mat. 

\section{display}
The cat sat on the mat. The cat sat on the mat. The cat sat on the mat. 
The cat sat on the mat. The cat sat on the mat. The cat sat on the mat. 
\[\lim_{b\to-\infty} \frac{x}{b} = ?\]
The cat sat on the mat. The cat sat on the mat. The cat sat on the mat. 
The cat sat on the mat. The cat sat on the mat. The cat sat on the mat. 







\end{document}
```