# How to force inline style in displaymath?

Tags: inline, displaystyle

In my Latex source file, I put `\everymath{\displaystyle}` in the preamble.
So every formula within $...$ will in displaymath style. In this circumstance, how to get an inline math style?

Comment: Code between `$...$` will still be typeset as inline math, `\displaystyle` only changes the way some parts of the math code are displayed, e.g. subscripts below operators instead of the normal subscript positioning. You can undo your global setting for a certain inline math by using `$\textstyle ...$`. But you probably shouldn't use your global setting in the first place; use `\[ ... \]` or `$\displaystyle ...$` where appropriate.

Comment: Did you see the posting [Show inline math as if it were display math](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/32824/5001)? The [most-upvoted answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/32827/5001) to that query -- shameless self-citation alert! -- shows how to go back and forth between `\displaystyle` and `\textstyle`.

Comment: by far the best way is not to use `\everymath{\displaystyle}` as it makes inline math unusable for its intended purpose but if you do do that you can use `\displaystyle` at the start of the expression to get back to normal https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/323367/i-have-a-question-about-the-displaystyle-command/323375#323375

Comment: sorry I meant to write "you can use `\textstyle` "

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I have tried, but it doesn't work.

Comment: `\textstyle` would work, if you have some code that does not work as you expect then it is always best to include a small complete document that reproduces the problem. However as I say in this case it is best simply not to use `\everymath{\displaystyle}` or only use it in a very restricted local group