# \everymath{\displaystyle} in ConTeXt

Tags: context, displaystyle

In LaTeX I can use `\everymath{\displaystyle}` to use display style as default and `\textstyle` to switch back to inline mode. However, when I try this on ConTeXt, the compiling crashes. How do I get something alike to `\everymath{\displaystyle}` without manually writing `\displaystyle` everywhere?

Comment: You should ***never*** use `\everymath{\displaystyle}`

Comment: Oh, thank you. I'm gonna keep it on mind.

Comment: Btw, what should I do in LaTeX instead?

Comment: Use `\displaystyle` when necessary, which is rarely the case.

Comment: See for example https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/323367/i-have-a-question-about-the-displaystyle-command/323375#323375  for why setting \displaystyle by default breaks most of the intended use cases for inline math mode.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please don't...

```
\appendtoks
    \displaystyle
\to \everymathematics

\starttext

$f(a) = \frac{1}{2 \pi i} \oint_\gamma \frac{f(z)}{z - a} dz$

\stoptext
```

[image]