# Preamble: something is suppressing fbox containing instructions at top of math worksheet

Tags: framed, fbox

Here's the instructions that aren't appearing when I compile in overleaf:

```
 \fbox{\fbox{\parbox{\dimexpr\textwidth-4\fboxsep-4\fboxrule}{
    \textbf {Simplify by expansion and steps shown in class. Your answer should have only POSITIVE EXPONENTS.
```

Not sure if this matters, there's an error at the 2nd last line of code `\end task`:

`underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph`

Thanks very much for taking time to read and respond to my query.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{exam}

%\printanswers % uncomment to print solutions.
\printanswers
\renewcommand{\solutiontitle}{}
% MACROS
%Not sure all of these packages are necessary...but the 'taks package is certainly necessary
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{caption} % allows captions in minipage envir (issue w/solutions envir)
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{framed} %box para
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{tasks}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}
%\displaystyle for all $$ math environments use \lim\limits for other environments

\usepackage[a4paper,margin=0.5in,include head]{geometry}

\everymath{\displaystyle}

%\unframedsolutions % uncomment to remove boxes from solutions

\setlength\parindent{1em}

\pagestyle{head}
\header{Pre-Alg. 8.1.6 D6 Exponents Quiz:Product and Product Properties }
       {}
       {03/10/20} 

\newcommand{\pagetop}{%
  \makebox[\textwidth]{Name:\enspace\hrulefill}\par
  \vspace{4mm}
  \fbox{\fbox{\parbox{\dimexpr\textwidth-4\fboxsep-4\fboxrule}{
    \textbf {Simplify by expansion and steps shown in class. Your answer should have only POSITIVE EXPONENTS.
     \bigskip
    \\Show all work/steps on this page.}

  }}}\par
  \bigskip
  \vspace{0.5mm}
}

\settasks{after-item-skip=1em,
          after-skip=2cm,
          label-width=2em,
          item-indent=3em,
          label=(\arabic*),
          column-sep=2em
          }

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% -------------------------- DOCUMENT STARTS HERE-------------------- 
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}

%\pagetop
\begin{tasks}%
[style=enumerate](2)
% Prob #1
\task $3x^4\cdot 4x^3$
\begin{solutionorbox}[5cm]
$8x^3y^0\cdot 7xy^3$
\\\\
$8^1x^3 \cancel{y^0}\cdot 7^1x^1y^3$
\\\\
$8^1\cdot 7^1\cdot x^3\cdot x^1 \cdot y^3$
\\\\
$8\cdot 7\cdot x\cdot x \cdot x\cdot x\cdot y\cdot y\cdot y$
\\\\
$8\cdot 7\cdot x^4\cdot y^3$
\\\\
$56x^4y^3$
\end{solutionorbox}
% Prob #2
\task $7x^2\cdot 4x^3$
\begin{solutionorbox}[5cm]
$-8uv^3\cdot 7u^4v^2$
\\\\
$(-8)^1u^1v^3 \cdot 7^1u^4v^2 $
\\\\
$(-8)^1\cdot 7^1\cdot u^1\cdot u^4\cdot v^3\cdot v^2$
\\\\
$(-8)\cdot 7\cdot u\cdot u\cdot u\cdot u\cdot u\cdot v\cdot v\cdot v\cdot v\cdot v$
\\\\
$(-8)\cdot 7\cdot u^5\cdot v^5$
\\\\
$-56u^5v^5$

\end{solutionorbox}


\end{tasks}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Your document produces the error `! LaTeX Error: \begin{document} ended by \end{tasks}.`  and is missing `\begin{document}` and `\begin{tasks}`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle...I apologize for not including more of the code in my MWE. I edited my OP to include all the relevant code. If you run it now, you'll notice the missing \hbox containing text for the math worksheet. Thanks for your assistance!

Comment: `\\\\ ` ouch:-)  that is what is generating all those warnings,

Comment: you are not very clear on what you expect, what text is  missing? you have some text in a command called `\pagetop` but you never use that command, or do you mean some different text?

Comment: just uncomment `%\pagetop` ?

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/334249/1090

Comment: Also on `\everymath` : https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/323375/1090

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, simple yet perfect fix! Many thanks! Any idea why -- despite the rendering being correct -- when I un-comment \page top an `overfill \hbox` occurs? Also, I appreciate the links you provided. **How can I mark my question as answered?**

Comment: the box is full width but indented by parindent so overfull by that amount

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The text doesn't appear as it is commented out, but apart from that it needs to be prefixed by `\noindent` as it is a full width box but indented as the start of a paragraph so sticks into the right margin with an overfull box warning.

The underfull box warnings are (as almost always the case) due to misuse of `\\`  simply replace the `\\\\` by a blank line and set up `\parskip` to give whatever vertical space you need between paragraphs.

Comment: The suggestion to set up `\parskip`  to create vertical space between lines and thereby eliminate the use of  `\\\\ ` is a huge time saver in terms of reduced keystrokes. Also, really cleans up the code.