# Way to shortcut `\limits` for a whole page

Tags: page, shortcut

Is it only me or does it get annoying whenever I've to write `\limits` before every operator? Is there a way to make that happen for *every* operator without having to list them all one by one?

```tex
\newcommand{\myint}{\int\limits} % <= Unwanted solution...
\myint_{\lambda_1}^{\lambda_2}
```

Context: I had to write over a thousand `limits` to realise really how redundant it is in my pdf... lol. So, I would really appreciate any tips.

Comment: Why are you adding `\limits` everytime in the first place?

Comment: @daleif It is better stylistically (and for readability) for the purposes of compiling multiple proofs about important theorems around Lebesgue integrals.

Comment: You wrote, "does it get annoying whenever I've to write `\limits` before every operator?" Real quick (just in case it wasn't a simple typo): The modifier `\limits` should be written *after*, not *before", the associated "operator" -- ``\int`, `\sum`, `\prod`, etc.

Comment: I was thinking of `_{...}` when I said operator (i.e. `\int\limts_{\lambda_1}`, sorry! @Mico

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`\int` is defined as `\DeclareRobustCommand\int{\intop\nolimits}` specifically to avoid getting limits so you could use `\intop` or simply repeat the definition without the `\nolimits` which is fine although going against the usual mathematical typesetting tradition.

Comment: This answers is tor my context (hence my acceptance), but could this be modified for every operator without going through them all or no?

Comment: `\int` is the only command defined in the base latex that has `\nolimits`  forced in this way. @Math3147 what other operator are you doing this with?

Comment: Not specifically one, just generally, do you know of any way this could be done without listing every operator in a `\newcommand`  way, as above? Or does it have to be listed always?

Comment: @Math3147 I do not understand the question. You only need to do `\DeclareRobustCommand\int{\intop}` so that is just one line and applies to every `\int` in the document. The problem you describe (defaulting to `\nolimits`) does not apply to anything other than `\int` so I do not  understand which operators you are "listing"

Comment: When you've `\sum` or `\bigoplus` , et cetera, when inline, don't you need to put `\limits`? Or for example, when `\limsup` is said without `\limits`, it will look different. Or am I misunderstanding what you're referring to? (If so, sorry!)

Comment: (I understand, you can use `\displaystyle`, but that's even longer, and it doesn't need to be typed as often as you could just put it and the whole math-mode block will look like what you might approximately want, or in this case, myself.)

Comment: that is completely different to the situation with `\int`, using limits completely breaks the intention of inline math setting so if you don't want that use display style

Comment: Yes, I understand, I'm referring to other ones, like I've exemplified. Your answers solve that already. :)
Also, there are many situations were the formulae are just too short or there are too many similar formulae that I would've put a display every couple of lines which looks stylistically unpleasant for pages on pages, thus why I still want to figure out if there is a general solution, if you're not aware of one, that's fine. Also, if you still think it is not an issue (even with the examples), then fine too.

Comment: I think you are asking for `\everymath{\displaystyle}`  but there are many reasons not to do that. @Math3147

Comment: Is there a post on this site that explains why not to do so? (Also, thank you, again... that will save me so much typing...)

Comment: @Math3147 https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/323367/1090

Comment: Thank you, David. :)

Answer (score 5):

You could load the `amsmath` package (or the `mathtools` package) with the option `intlimits` in order to save yourself from having to type

```
\int\limits
```

each and every time.

Comment: ah I should have remembered that: if the OP moves the tick I may delete mine:-)

Comment: Thank you, that seems like a viable solution too. :)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle please don't: your answer is useful for those who use not-really-LaTeX parsers (like MathJax) and can't control options in packages. `\intop` works fine there.