# How to display inline math display-style document-wide

Tags: inline, displaystyle

I have a document where I want to display both inline and display math in the larger display-style.  I know that for inline math I can add `\displaystyle` between the dollar signs, but I want to do this automatically for the entire document without have to keep typing that.

Is there a command I can re-define?

Comment: `\everymath{\displaystyle}` but... https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/323375/1090

Comment: It seems then that line spacing overall should be increased for consistency with the wild `\displaystyle`.  Is that a good typographical solution for the occasional inline math equation using `\displaystyle`?

Comment: To my opinion, no. It have been deliberately designed `inline` math style. Use of `\displaystyle` destroy uniform spacing of text lines when you for example use $\sum_{i=0}^{1}$. See link which provide @DavidCarlisle in his comment..

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Yes, perfectly.