# Extra alignment tab error trying to justify within cases environment

Tags: errors, equations, align, cases

I am trying to align brackets inside of `cases`. This is my equation:

```
\begin{align}
y(x)=
\begin{cases}
  \bigg[ & 1+2 & \\
         & +5+6 \bigg] & \text{if } x < 2, \\
  \bigg[ & 11+12 & \\
        & +15+16 \bigg] & \text{if }x > 2,\\
        0 & & \text{otherwise.}
\end{cases} 
\end{align}
```

When I compile this, I get the following error

```
! Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr.
```

The same happens when I remove the `align` environment change it to `equation` instead.

```
\begin{equation}
y(x)=
\begin{cases}
  \bigg[ & 1+2 & \\
        & +5+6 \bigg] & \text{if } x < 2, \\
  \bigg[ & 11+12 & \\
        & +15+16 \bigg] & \text{if }x > 2,\\
        0  & & \text{otherwise.}
\end{cases} 
\end{equation}
```

I searched for this problem, but all the questions seem to be about `table` environments.

Comment: I think you can only use a single alignment tab (&) per case. When I delete the second & in each case, the error goes away.

Comment: Right, it works that way. I was wondering if its possible to align brackets inside my multiline cases to make it easier to understand which brackets pair up.

Comment: Please complete your code so it produces the error you report. Right now it obviously will not get that far.

Answer (score 1):

Nick has explained by this doesn't work. Two possible workarounds are shown below, one using `array` instead of `cases`, the other using a `multlined` (requires the `mathtools` package) inside `cases`.

And note that for single equations you should be using `equation`, not `align` ([align vs equation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/321/align-vs-equation)).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
y(x)= \left\{
\begin{array}{@{\,}r@{}ll}
  \biggl[ & 1+2 & \\
        & +5+6 \biggr] & \text{if } x < 2, \\
  \biggl[ & 11+12 & \\
        & +15+16 \biggr] & \text{if }x > 2,\\
        0  & & \text{otherwise.}
\end{array}\right.
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
y(x)=
\begin{cases}
  \begin{multlined}[b]
   \bigg[1+2  \\
        +5+6 \bigg]
\end{multlined} & \text{if } x < 2, \\
  \begin{multlined}[b]
\bigg[11+12  \\
        +15+16 \bigg]
\end{multlined} & \text{if }x > 2,\\
        0  &  \text{otherwise.}
\end{cases} 
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]