# Invalid use of \intertext

Tags: errors, amsmath, texmaker

I'm writing a report. I first did it on [ShareLaTeX](http://www.sharelatex.com) and it compiled successfully. Now, I'm redoing it on *texmaker* and it doesn't compile stating the following error: "invalid use of \intertext".

The part on the code in which I get the error is this one:

```
\begin{subequations}
\begin{align}\label{eq:twoa}
    \begin{split}
    J\dot{\omega}=rF_z \mu \left(\dfrac{v-\omega r}{v}\right)-T_b \\
    m\dot{v}=-F_z \mu \left(\dfrac{v-\omega r}{v}\right)
    \end{split}      
\end{align}
\intertext{\noindent In (\ref{eq:twoa}) the state variables are $\omega$ and $v$. Since $\omega$, $v$, and $\lambda$ are linked by an algebraic relationship, it is possible to replace the state variable $\omega$ with the state variable $\lambda$. This can be simply obtained by plugging the following two relationships 
\begin{align*}
    \dot{\lambda}=-\dfrac{r}{v}\dot{\omega} + \dfrac{r\omega}{v^2}\dot{v}, \hspace{4mm} \omega=\dfrac{v}{r}(1-\lambda)
\end{align*}
into the first equation of (\ref{eq:twoa}), so obtaining:}

\begin{align}\label{eq:twob}
    \begin{split}
    \dot{\lambda}=-\dfrac{1}{v}\left(\dfrac{(1-\lambda)}{m}+\dfrac{r^2}{J}\right) F_z \mu(\lambda) + \dfrac{r}{vJ}T_b \\
    m\dot{v}=-F_z\mu(\lambda)
    \end{split}      
\end{align}
\end{subequations}
```

And actually the output is this one in ShareLaTeX (what I need):
[image]

But I can't make it work in *texmaker*, I keep getting the "invalid use of \intertext" error message. What should I do to fix this on *texmaker*? Or how could I get the same output properly?

Comment: That would be equally wrong regardless of ShareLaTeX or Texmaker, you probably just ignored/missed the errors that ShareLaTeX told you about. `\intertext` is meant to be placed *inside* an `align` environment.

Comment: Also, next time, please post a full minimal example instead of jut a sniplet. Then it is easy for others to copy and test your exact example on their own PCs. Thus much easier for us to help. As Torbjørn mentions, `\intertext` does not make any sense out side of `align(*)`, `alignat(*)` and `gather(*)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't really need `\intertext` at all here, just remove it. Also, don't use `align` for single-line equations ([align vs equation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/321/align-vs-equation)).

[image: output of code]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{subequations}
\begin{equation}\label{eq:twoa}
    \begin{split}
    J\dot{\omega}=rF_z \mu \left(\dfrac{v-\omega r}{v}\right)-T_b \\
    m\dot{v}=-F_z \mu \left(\dfrac{v-\omega r}{v}\right)
    \end{split}      
\end{equation}
In (\ref{eq:twoa}) the state variables are $\omega$ and $v$. Since $\omega$, $v$, and $\lambda$ are linked by an algebraic relationship, it is possible to replace the state variable $\omega$ with the state variable $\lambda$. This can be simply obtained by plugging the following two relationships 
\begin{equation*}
    \dot{\lambda}=-\dfrac{r}{v}\dot{\omega} + \dfrac{r\omega}{v^2}\dot{v}, \hspace{4mm} \omega=\dfrac{v}{r}(1-\lambda)
\end{equation*}
into the first equation of (\ref{eq:twoa}), so obtaining:
\begin{equation}\label{eq:twob}
    \begin{split}
    \dot{\lambda}=-\dfrac{1}{v}\left(\dfrac{(1-\lambda)}{m}+\dfrac{r^2}{J}\right) F_z \mu(\lambda) + \dfrac{r}{vJ}T_b \\
    m\dot{v}=-F_z\mu(\lambda)
    \end{split}      
\end{equation}
\end{subequations}
\end{document}
```

Regarding ShareLaTeX, I guess you see something like this:

[image]

Notice that little red box with the number 1 in it? That means that you got one error. While the output of a document with errors is sometimes correct, that is just luck, so you should always make sure to not have any errors. If you click that icon with the red box, you'll see what the error says:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, I was wrong with the use of \intertext. Thank you for the quick reply!

Comment: @Airman01 No worries. I added a little section on ShareLaTeX and errors.

Comment: Thank you! I was almost sure it was correct but now I realized there was an error.