# overuse of alignat environment

Tags: equations, alignat

I am editing a student's paper, and I noticed that he uses `alignat` for every equation, even single-line equations, like:

```
\begin{alignat}{1} 
x = y^2
\end{alignat}
```

I was about to comment that he should use `equation` for single-line equations and save `alignat` (or `align`) for multi-line equations, but then I realized -- maybe there's no harm in just using `alignat` everywhere.

Thoughts?

Comment: Did you see the posting [align vs equation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/321/5001)? (`alignat{1}` and `align` are basically the same.)

Comment: I did not! Thanks for linking. Feel free to close this question as duplicate. (Is that the right protocol?)